# Bluetooth not working on ubuntu14.04

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
is giving this output

```
[   31.384146] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[   31.384170] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager   initialized
[   31.384180] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   31.384184] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   31.384196] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   31.500587] Bluetooth: can't load firmware, may not work correctly
[   33.506073] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
```

and in the last

```
[ 5703.089302] Workqueue: hci0 hci_power_on [bluetooth]
[ 5703.089347]  [<ffffffffa0534bd5>] hci_dev_do_open+0x275/0x760      [bluetooth]
[ 5703.089356]  [<ffffffffa05356b0>] hci_power_on+0x40/0x180 [bluetooth]
[ 5703.089388] Bluetooth: can't load firmware, may not work correctly
[ 5705.093470] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
```

rfkill list output :-

```
10: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

lsusb output:-

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 064e:930b Suyin Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0a5c:216d Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

what can i do to get bluetooth working?
it cannot be discovered by other devices and it cannot discover other devices.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: i have edited the question @Pilot6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to install 3.19 kernel by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

And then follow the [GUIDE](https://askubuntu.com/a/632348/167850) to obtain, convert and install firmware.

It is not legal to distribute the firmware.

But I found a newer driver [HERE](http://devid.info/ru/68560).

New devices have been added and firmware files are newer.

Comment: is it required to install to install 3.19 kernel? @Pilot6

Comment: @DebajyotiChatterjee You can try without upgrading kernel. But that is a supported Ubuntu kernel, that will get updates. I recommend to upgrade. There are bluetooth fixes too.

Comment: it worked , thank you so much @Pilot6