# 14.04 bluetooth Unable to select SEP

Tags: 14.04, drivers, bluetooth, broadcom

in the past I had problem getting the bluetooth to work. although I fixed it with [ubuntu 14.04 bluetooth BCM43142 no discovery (tx timeout)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653743/ubuntu-14-04-bluetooth-bcm43142-no-discovery-tx-timeout) i still had issue with lags and skips [14.04 bluetooth lag (latency, delay) and skipping](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655778/14-04-bluetooth-lag-latency-delay-and-skipping)

now I cannot even pair to a device. here are some details:

```
$ uname -r
3.19.0-26-generic

$ cat /etc/*release* | grep -i dist
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"

$ lspci -nnk | grep -i network -A 2
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel driver in use: wl

$ lsmod | grep -i 'bluetooth\|btusb\|wl'
btusb                  40960  0 
wl                   6369280  0 
cfg80211              524288  1 wl
bluetooth             491520  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm

$ lsusb | grep -i bluetooth
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0

T:  Bus=04 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=04 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0a5c ProdID=21d7 Rev=01.12
S:  Manufacturer=Broadcom Corp
S:  Product=BCM43142A0
S:  SerialNumber=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
C:  #Ifs= 4 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=fe(app. ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)


$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: c0:18:85:bc:70:ef
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=192.168.1.103 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:16 memory:d0500000-d0507fff

$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[    3.060119] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    3.060139] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.060142] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.060145] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.060151] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.063204] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.063207] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.063210] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    3.068272] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    3.068279] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    3.068285] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    3.518076] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patching hci_ver=06 hci_rev=007e lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=210b
[    4.108756] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware hci_ver=06 hci_rev=007e lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=210b

$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i bluetooth
Sep  8 18:33:19 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.034821] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
Sep  8 18:33:19 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.034838] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Sep  8 18:33:19 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.034842] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Sep  8 18:33:19 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.034845] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Sep  8 18:33:19 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.034850] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Sep  8 18:33:19 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.046775] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Sep  8 18:33:19 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.046778] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Sep  8 18:33:19 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.046783] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Sep  8 18:33:19 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.047732] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Sep  8 18:33:19 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.047739] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Sep  8 18:33:19 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.047744] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
Sep  8 18:33:20 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Unknown command complete for opcode 19
Sep  8 18:33:20 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Adapter /org/bluez/540/hci0 has been enabled
Sep  8 18:33:20 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: sap-dummy interface org.bluez.SimAccessTest init failed on path /org/bluez/test
Sep  8 18:33:20 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Sep  8 18:33:20 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Sep  8 18:33:20 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Unknown command complete for opcode 19
Sep  8 18:33:20 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Adapter /org/bluez/540/hci1 has been enabled
Sep  8 18:33:20 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.416582] Bluetooth: hci1: BCM: patching hci_ver=06 hci_rev=0000 lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=210b
Sep  8 18:33:20 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.969139] Bluetooth: hci1: BCM: firmware hci_ver=06 hci_rev=007e lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=210b
Sep  8 18:33:23 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.33 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  8 18:33:23 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.33 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  8 18:33:23 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.33 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  8 18:33:23 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.33 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  8 18:33:23 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.33 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  8 18:33:23 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.33 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  8 18:33:23 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.33 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  8 18:33:23 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.33 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  8 18:33:54 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.70 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  8 18:33:54 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.70 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  8 18:33:54 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.70 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  8 18:33:54 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.70 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  8 18:33:54 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.70 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  8 18:33:54 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.70 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  8 18:33:54 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.70 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  8 18:33:54 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.70 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  8 18:33:55 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.70 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  8 18:33:55 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.70 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  8 18:33:55 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.70 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  8 18:33:55 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.70 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  8 18:33:55 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.70 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  8 18:33:55 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.70 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  8 18:33:55 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.70 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  8 18:33:55 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.70 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  8 18:34:13 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.33 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  8 18:34:13 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.33 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  8 18:34:13 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.33 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  8 18:34:13 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.33 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  8 18:34:13 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.33 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  8 18:34:13 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.33 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  8 18:34:13 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.33 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  8 18:34:13 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.33 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  8 18:34:13 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: hci0: Remove UUID (0x0011) failed: Busy (0x0a)
Sep  8 18:34:13 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: hci1: Remove UUID (0x0011) failed: Busy (0x0a)
Sep  8 18:47:32 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Adapter /org/bluez/540/hci0 has been disabled
Sep  8 18:47:32 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Unregister path: /org/bluez/540/hci0
Sep  8 18:47:32 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: hci0: Set IO Capability (0x0018) failed: Invalid Index (0x11)
Sep  8 18:47:38 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: sap-dummy interface org.bluez.SimAccessTest init failed on path /org/bluez/test
Sep  8 18:47:38 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Sep  8 18:47:38 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Sep  8 18:47:38 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Unknown command complete for opcode 19
Sep  8 18:47:39 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Adapter /org/bluez/540/hci0 has been enabled
Sep  8 18:58:03 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Adapter /org/bluez/540/hci1 has been disabled
Sep  8 18:58:07 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Adapter /org/bluez/540/hci1 has been enabled
Sep  8 18:58:38 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Adapter /org/bluez/540/hci0 has been disabled
Sep  8 18:58:38 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Unregister path: /org/bluez/540/hci0
Sep  8 18:58:38 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: hci0: Set IO Capability (0x0018) failed: Invalid Index (0x11)
Sep  8 18:58:39 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: sap-dummy interface org.bluez.SimAccessTest init failed on path /org/bluez/test
Sep  8 18:58:39 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Sep  8 18:58:39 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Sep  8 18:58:39 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Unknown command complete for opcode 19
Sep  8 18:58:39 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: hci0: Set Powered (0x0005) failed: Busy (0x0a)
Sep  8 18:58:39 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Adapter /org/bluez/540/hci0 has been enabled
Sep  8 18:58:39 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Adapter /org/bluez/540/hci0 has been disabled
Sep  8 18:58:39 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Unregister path: /org/bluez/540/hci0
Sep  8 18:58:39 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: hci0: Set IO Capability (0x0018) failed: Invalid Index (0x11)
Sep  8 18:58:47 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: sap-dummy interface org.bluez.SimAccessTest init failed on path /org/bluez/test
Sep  8 18:58:47 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Sep  8 18:58:47 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Sep  8 18:58:47 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Unknown command complete for opcode 19
Sep  8 18:58:47 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Adapter /org/bluez/540/hci0 has been enabled
Sep  8 19:01:14 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Discovery session 0x7f44df770ad0 with :1.97 activated
Sep  8 19:01:21 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Stopping discovery
Sep  8 19:01:22 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Discovery session 0x7f44df76fbc0 with :1.97 activated
Sep  8 19:01:33 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Stopping discovery
Sep  8 19:01:50 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Unable to select SEP
Sep  8 19:06:44 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: message repeated 5 times: [ Unable to select SEP]
Sep  8 19:07:01 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Discovery session 0x7f44df763bf0 with :1.97 activated
Sep  8 19:07:12 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Stopping discovery
Sep  8 19:07:37 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Unable to select SEP
Sep  8 19:08:10 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: message repeated 2 times: [ Unable to select SEP]
Sep  8 19:08:49 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: No GATT server found in C0:18:85:BC:70:F0
Sep  8 19:08:49 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: No GATT server found in C0:18:85:BC:70:F0
Sep  8 19:08:49 xxxxxx bluetoothd[540]: Attribute server attach failure!
Sep  8 19:09:19 xxxxxx kernel: [ 2165.739633] bluetoothd[540]: segfault at c8 ip 00007f44dea88700 sp 00007fff7bd3cf18 error 4 in libdbus-1.so.3.7.6[7f44dea7f000+44000]
Sep  8 19:09:19 xxxxxx kernel: [ 2165.859147] init: bluetooth main process (540) killed by SEGV signal
Sep  8 19:09:19 xxxxxx kernel: [ 2165.859161] init: bluetooth main process ended, respawning
Sep  8 19:09:19 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Bluetooth daemon 4.101
Sep  8 19:09:19 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Starting SDP server
Sep  8 19:09:19 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: DIS cannot start: GATT is disabled
Sep  8 19:09:19 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Failed to init deviceinfo plugin
Sep  8 19:09:19 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Failed to init proximity plugin
Sep  8 19:09:19 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Failed to init time plugin
Sep  8 19:09:19 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Failed to init alert plugin
Sep  8 19:09:19 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Failed to init thermometer plugin
Sep  8 19:09:19 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
Sep  8 19:09:19 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized
Sep  8 19:09:19 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Adapter /org/bluez/4981/hci0 has been enabled
Sep  8 19:09:19 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: sap-dummy interface org.bluez.SimAccessTest init failed on path /org/bluez/test
Sep  8 19:09:19 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Sep  8 19:09:19 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Sep  8 19:09:19 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Adapter /org/bluez/4981/hci1 has been enabled
Sep  8 19:09:19 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Unknown command complete for opcode 19
Sep  8 19:09:19 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Unknown command complete for opcode 19
Sep  8 19:09:35 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Discovery session 0x7f3e3e9059c0 with :1.103 activated
Sep  8 19:09:43 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Unknown command complete for opcode 37
Sep  8 19:10:00 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Stopping discovery
Sep  8 19:10:05 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Unable to select SEP
Sep  8 19:11:00 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: message repeated 5 times: [ Unable to select SEP]
Sep  8 19:11:03 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Adapter /org/bluez/4981/hci0 has been disabled
Sep  8 19:11:03 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Unregister path: /org/bluez/4981/hci0
Sep  8 19:11:07 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Discovery session 0x7f3e3e8e9dd0 with :1.104 activated
Sep  8 19:11:11 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Stopping discovery
Sep  8 19:11:12 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Discovery session 0x7f3e3e8ee3c0 with :1.104 activated
Sep  8 19:11:22 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Stopping discovery
Sep  8 19:11:47 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Unable to select SEP
Sep  8 19:12:03 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Discovery session 0x7f3e3e8f3a60 with :1.104 activated
Sep  8 19:12:13 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Stopping discovery
Sep  8 19:12:26 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Unable to select SEP
Sep  8 19:13:19 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: message repeated 3 times: [ Unable to select SEP]
Sep  8 19:13:29 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Discovery session 0x7f3e3e8ee3c0 with :1.104 activated
Sep  8 19:13:39 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Stopping discovery
Sep  8 19:14:05 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Unable to select SEP
Sep  8 19:14:21 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Unable to select SEP
Sep  8 19:14:26 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Discovery session 0x7f3e3e8f14b0 with :1.104 activated
Sep  8 19:14:36 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Stopping discovery
Sep  8 19:14:56 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Unable to select SEP
Sep  8 19:15:01 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Discovery session 0x7f3e3e8ee3c0 with :1.104 activated
Sep  8 19:15:11 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Stopping discovery
Sep  8 19:15:36 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Discovery session 0x7f3e3e8e9dd0 with :1.104 activated
Sep  8 19:15:46 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Stopping discovery
Sep  8 19:16:22 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Unable to select SEP
Sep  8 19:19:29 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Unable to select SEP
Sep  8 19:19:35 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Discovery session 0x7f3e3e8ee3c0 with :1.104 activated
Sep  8 19:19:45 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Stopping discovery
Sep  8 19:20:10 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Unable to select SEP
Sep  8 19:20:27 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Discovery session 0x7f3e3e907400 with :1.104 activated
Sep  8 19:20:37 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Stopping discovery
Sep  8 19:20:57 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Unable to select SEP
Sep  8 19:21:30 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Terminating
Sep  8 19:21:30 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Stopping SDP server
Sep  8 19:21:30 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4981]: Exit
Sep  8 19:21:30 xxxxxx bluetoothd[5300]: Bluetooth daemon 4.101
Sep  8 19:21:30 xxxxxx bluetoothd[5300]: Starting SDP server
Sep  8 19:21:30 xxxxxx bluetoothd[5300]: DIS cannot start: GATT is disabled
Sep  8 19:21:30 xxxxxx bluetoothd[5300]: Failed to init deviceinfo plugin
Sep  8 19:21:30 xxxxxx bluetoothd[5300]: Failed to init proximity plugin
Sep  8 19:21:30 xxxxxx bluetoothd[5300]: Failed to init time plugin
Sep  8 19:21:30 xxxxxx bluetoothd[5300]: Failed to init alert plugin
Sep  8 19:21:30 xxxxxx bluetoothd[5300]: Failed to init thermometer plugin
Sep  8 19:21:30 xxxxxx bluetoothd[5300]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
Sep  8 19:21:30 xxxxxx bluetoothd[5300]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized
Sep  8 19:21:30 xxxxxx bluetoothd[5300]: Adapter /org/bluez/5300/hci1 has been enabled
Sep  8 19:21:30 xxxxxx bluetoothd[5300]: Unknown command complete for opcode 19
Sep  8 19:22:50 xxxxxx bluetoothd[5300]: Unable to select SEP
Sep  8 19:25:17 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.054018] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
Sep  8 19:25:17 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.054033] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Sep  8 19:25:17 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.054037] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Sep  8 19:25:17 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.054039] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Sep  8 19:25:17 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.054045] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Sep  8 19:25:17 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.057103] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Sep  8 19:25:17 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.057106] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Sep  8 19:25:17 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.057110] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Sep  8 19:25:17 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.069291] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Sep  8 19:25:17 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.069299] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Sep  8 19:25:17 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.069305] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
Sep  8 19:25:18 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Unknown command complete for opcode 19
Sep  8 19:25:18 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Adapter /org/bluez/545/hci0 has been enabled
Sep  8 19:25:18 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.462801] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patching hci_ver=06 hci_rev=007e lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=210b
Sep  8 19:25:18 xxxxxx kernel: [    4.058914] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware hci_ver=06 hci_rev=007e lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=210b
Sep  8 19:25:21 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.35 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  8 19:25:21 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.35 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  8 19:25:21 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.35 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  8 19:25:21 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.35 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  8 19:25:51 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.71 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  8 19:25:51 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.71 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  8 19:25:51 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.71 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  8 19:25:51 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.71 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  8 19:25:52 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.71 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  8 19:25:52 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.71 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  8 19:25:52 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.71 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  8 19:25:52 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.71 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  8 19:26:10 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.35 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  8 19:26:10 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.35 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  8 19:26:10 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.35 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  8 19:26:10 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.35 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  8 19:26:10 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: hci0: Remove UUID (0x0011) failed: Busy (0x0a)
Sep  8 19:26:54 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Discovery session 0x7eff0913d5a0 with :1.94 activated
Sep  8 19:27:05 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Stopping discovery
Sep  8 19:28:56 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Unable to select SEP
Sep  8 19:33:34 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: message repeated 2 times: [ Unable to select SEP]
Sep  8 19:36:20 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Terminating
Sep  8 19:36:20 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Stopping SDP server
Sep  8 19:36:20 xxxxxx bluetoothd[545]: Exit
Sep  8 19:36:23 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4344]: Bluetooth daemon 4.101
Sep  8 19:36:23 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4344]: Starting SDP server
Sep  8 19:36:23 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4344]: DIS cannot start: GATT is disabled
Sep  8 19:36:23 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4344]: Failed to init deviceinfo plugin
Sep  8 19:36:23 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4344]: Failed to init proximity plugin
Sep  8 19:36:23 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4344]: Failed to init time plugin
Sep  8 19:36:23 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4344]: Failed to init alert plugin
Sep  8 19:36:23 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4344]: Failed to init thermometer plugin
Sep  8 19:36:23 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4344]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
Sep  8 19:36:23 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4344]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized
Sep  8 19:36:23 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4344]: Adapter /org/bluez/4344/hci0 has been enabled
Sep  8 19:36:23 xxxxxx bluetoothd[4344]: Unknown command complete for opcode 19
Sep  8 19:38:56 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.060119] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
Sep  8 19:38:56 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.060139] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Sep  8 19:38:56 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.060142] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Sep  8 19:38:56 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.060145] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Sep  8 19:38:56 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.060151] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Sep  8 19:38:56 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.063204] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Sep  8 19:38:56 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.063207] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Sep  8 19:38:56 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.063210] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Sep  8 19:38:56 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.068272] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Sep  8 19:38:56 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.068279] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Sep  8 19:38:56 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.068285] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
Sep  8 19:38:57 xxxxxx bluetoothd[558]: Unknown command complete for opcode 19
Sep  8 19:38:57 xxxxxx kernel: [    3.518076] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patching hci_ver=06 hci_rev=007e lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=210b
Sep  8 19:38:57 xxxxxx kernel: [    4.108756] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware hci_ver=06 hci_rev=007e lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=210b
Sep  8 19:38:57 xxxxxx bluetoothd[558]: Adapter /org/bluez/558/hci0 has been enabled
Sep  8 19:39:00 xxxxxx bluetoothd[558]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.35 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  8 19:39:00 xxxxxx bluetoothd[558]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.35 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  8 19:39:00 xxxxxx bluetoothd[558]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.35 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  8 19:39:00 xxxxxx bluetoothd[558]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.35 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  8 19:39:05 xxxxxx bluetoothd[558]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.62 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  8 19:39:05 xxxxxx bluetoothd[558]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.62 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  8 19:39:05 xxxxxx bluetoothd[558]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.62 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  8 19:39:05 xxxxxx bluetoothd[558]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.62 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  8 19:39:06 xxxxxx bluetoothd[558]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.62 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  8 19:39:06 xxxxxx bluetoothd[558]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.62 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  8 19:39:06 xxxxxx bluetoothd[558]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.62 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  8 19:39:06 xxxxxx bluetoothd[558]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.62 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  8 19:39:24 xxxxxx bluetoothd[558]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.35 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  8 19:39:24 xxxxxx bluetoothd[558]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.35 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  8 19:39:24 xxxxxx bluetoothd[558]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.35 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  8 19:39:24 xxxxxx bluetoothd[558]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.35 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  8 19:39:24 xxxxxx bluetoothd[558]: hci0: Remove UUID (0x0011) failed: Busy (0x0a)
Sep  8 19:40:56 xxxxxx bluetoothd[558]: Discovery session 0x7f631cc6c5a0 with :1.92 activated
Sep  8 19:41:07 xxxxxx bluetoothd[558]: Stopping discovery
Sep  8 19:41:40 xxxxxx bluetoothd[558]: Unable to select SEP
```

please see the last message (`Unable to select SEP`), maybe this points somewhere.

I couldn't find any solution online.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working on ubuntu 15.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu-15-04)

Comment: @Pilot6 Not a duplicate `Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patching hci_ver=06 hci_rev=007e lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=210b` indicates firmware was loaded

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=964031#c3 might be worth a try

Comment: @Jeremy31: i followed you link, but it does not help. thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[executing](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1199059/comments/20)

```
$ pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

solved it for me.
if pulseaudio does not load the `module-bluetooth-discover` on boot (startup), check out [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2194428).

Comment: Good find as I haven't seen the error before