# Unable to find a source package for linux-lts-vivid

Tags: apt, kernel

As part of the [install process](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/doc/installation.md) for the Intel Realsense package, a script tries to run the line:

```
$ apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

I understand that this should get the source code for the current linux kernal. However, it returns the following error:

```
$     apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'linux-lts-vivid' as source package instead of 'linux-image-3.19.0-37-generic'
E: Unable to find a source package for linux-lts-vivid
```

I also tried directly doing:

```
$ apt-get source linux-lts-vivid
```

...but this had the same problem.

What can I do to correctly run this? I'm on 14.04 LTS, and I've already run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Looks you forgot to provide a link to the install process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`linux-lts-vivid` is obsolete.

You can upgrade to a supported kernel by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

Then reboot and try again.

Comment: Thanks - will this actually change my kernel? And could this affect things like my graphics drivers, CUDA installation etc?

Comment: It will upgrade your kernel to 4.4. Kernel 3.19 is not supported.

Comment: Kernel upgrades always affect *all* device drivers. This means out-of-tree kernel modules and software relying on a particular kernel version may break. For graphics drivers you should upgrade the full HWE stack including X.org.

Comment: @DavidFoerster There us no need to upgrade X.org in most cases, but it is recommended. I frequently upgrade only kernel.

Comment: Me too, but a switch to a different kernel branch may break other parts of X.org too (not just graphics).