# Broadcom bluetooth adapter is not recongnized (0a5c:2045)

Tags: bluetooth, broadcom, 15.10

I cannot find the corresponding windows hex file too for 0a5c:2045 to try this solution : https://github.com/advancingu/XPS13Linux/issues/1

As requested the log of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 06)


DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:1027]

--
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10d3]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:1027]


Kernel driver in use: e1000e
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2717:1260  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:2045 Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 17ef:6019 Lenovo 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0461:4e04 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The adapter I am using has id 0a5c:2045 , for which i could not get the windows hex file too.

```
  $ uname -a; hciconfig -a
Linux ankur-ThinkStation-D30 4.2.0-19-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 11 11:39:30 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working on ubuntu 15.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu-15-04)

Comment: I had tried the solution mentioned above but the hex file for 0a5c:2045 is not available in the cab file :(

Comment: Edit to include `uname -a; hciconfig -a` as there might be a fix

Comment: Included the uname destails , but no output from hciconfig -a , please check

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the BCM2045 that was recently fixed upstream, I have applied a patch to the kernel source

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/y4c8nm8fr1f2amx/bluetooth-4.2.tar.gz
tar -zxvf bluetooth-4.2.tar.gz
cd bluetooth
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
sudo mv /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko /lib/modules/(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko.bak
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/4.2.0-18-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko
```

Reboot and see if it corrects the issue with the bluetooth, if it is confirmed to work, I can make a DKMS version that will not have to be recompiled when you update to a newer kernel

The patch I used originated from [here](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/bluetooth/bluetooth-next.git/commit/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c?id=6c9d435d359898868f71e8ba03f8d5f1cbccaa69)

Comment: Sorry, but i could not see bluetooth device on _hcitool_  _scan_ after the above.

Comment: Anything from `hciconfig -a`

Comment: no output from 'hciconfig -a'

Comment: You may just have to wait for Ubuntu to patch their own kernel using the upstream patch