# Ubuntu 14.04 problems with Bluetooth [105b:e065] on Lenovo laptop

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, lenovo

i have ubuntu 14.04 on my Lenovo G500. I don't know why, but when I activate bluetooth in the control panel or in blueman nothing happen. Help me please, TY!

Sry for duplicate question, I'm newbee in "Linux World" and can't understand what I should to do...

Mb it can help

```
dmesg | grep Bluetooth
[    5.408892] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    5.408913] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.408916] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.408920] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.408927] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.414020] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    5.414027] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    5.414031] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    5.418647] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.418650] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.418654] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

and

```
lsmod | grep bluetooth
bluetooth             491520  11 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
```

and mb that

```
uname -a; lsusb
Linux inyellowbus-laptop 3.19.0-39-generic #44~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 2 10:00:35 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 105b:e065  
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 12d1:1051 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:5728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 09da:3010 A4 Tech Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1a2c:0c23 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 0):

This adapter is not supported by Ubuntu kernel yet. It will be supported in newer kernels, but I build a dkms module for kernel 4.2. I suggest to do the following:

1. Install kernel 4.2 by running:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
   ```

and reboot.

2. Install the `btusb` module:

   ```
   wget https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/bluetooth/+files/btusb-bcm105b-dkms_0.1_all.deb
   sudo dpkg -i btusb-bcm105b-dkms_0.1_all.deb
   ```
3. Convert and install firmware using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/632348/167850).

For kernel 4.2 probably you will need to rename the file to `BCM.hcd`.

4. Reboot and test bluetooth.

Comment: i'm so sorry about my post at another question. Promise that it will not happen again. Convert and install firmware, i can't find bluetooth on lsusb, like point 3, what i should to do?

Comment: Your bluetooth is `105b:e065 `.