# Bluetooth not working on Ubuntu 15.10 with BCM43142

Tags: bluetooth, 15.10

update:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b3aa Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0489:e062 Foxconn / Hon Hai
```

I cannot get the same Bluetooth message in terminal as [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu)

The Raw Question:

I'm a newbie for Ubuntu. I have installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my Sony SVF15316SCW (Vaio) computer. Everything is OK but my bluetooth is not working.I cannot find any bluetooth device in my bluetooth list though I open the BlueTooth switch.

[shot picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpur5.jpg)

And when I try to open BlueTooth again, I cannot get any response though I take on the bluetooth switch.

I tried to search solution and print some messages.

```
$ uname -a; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware; lsmod | grep bluetooth

Linux wangyeming-SVF15316SCW 4.2.0-22-generic #27-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 22:57:08 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e071]
Kernel driver in use: wl
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
Subsystem: Sony Corporation Device [104d:90be]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b3aa Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e062 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 2717:0368  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    3.056377] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    3.056395] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.056400] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.056403] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.056409] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.163815] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
[    8.194226] Modules linked in: bbswitch(OE) pn544_mei mei_phy pn544 hci nfc intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec crct10dif_pclmul snd_hda_core wl(POE) crc32_pclmul snd_hwdep snd_pcm btusb btrtl snd_seq_midi uvcvideo aesni_intel snd_seq_midi_event btbcm aes_x86_64 videobuf2_vmalloc lrw btintel gf128mul videobuf2_memops glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd videobuf2_core bluetooth snd_rawmidi nvidia(POE) v4l2_common cfg80211 snd_seq videodev input_leds joydev media serio_raw snd_seq_device rtsx_pci_ms snd_timer memstick lpc_ich snd shpchp sony_laptop mei_me soundcore mei tpm_crb mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 uas usb_storage rtsx_pci_sdmmc i915 ahci psmouse i2c_algo_bit
[    9.497516] Modules linked in: bbswitch(OE) pn544_mei mei_phy pn544 hci nfc intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec crct10dif_pclmul snd_hda_core wl(POE) crc32_pclmul snd_hwdep snd_pcm btusb btrtl snd_seq_midi uvcvideo aesni_intel snd_seq_midi_event btbcm aes_x86_64 videobuf2_vmalloc lrw btintel gf128mul videobuf2_memops glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd videobuf2_core bluetooth snd_rawmidi nvidia(POE) v4l2_common cfg80211 snd_seq videodev input_leds joydev media serio_raw snd_seq_device rtsx_pci_ms snd_timer memstick lpc_ich snd shpchp sony_laptop mei_me soundcore mei tpm_crb mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 uas usb_storage rtsx_pci_sdmmc i915 ahci psmouse i2c_algo_bit
[   10.000818] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   10.000822] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   10.000826] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   13.159433] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)
[   13.164310] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   13.164317] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[   13.168123] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[   13.168130] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   15.166288] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
[    0.133785] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.260860] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[   13.168123] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
bluetooth             516096  10 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,btintel
```

and

```
$ dmesg |grep Bluetooth
[    3.056377] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    3.056395] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager    initialized
[    3.056400] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.056403] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.056409] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.163815] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   10.000818] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   10.000822] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   10.000826] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   13.159433] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)
[   13.164310] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   13.164317] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[   13.168130] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   15.166288] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
```

Comment: I cannot find the any Bluetooth messages by lsusb. Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: `0489:e062 Foxconn / Hon Hai ` is your BT device.

Comment: Got it! Thank you! I will try your solution soon!

Answer (score 0):

use the commande `rfkill unblock bluetooth` to enable your bluetooth. You will find your bluetooth device in settings -> bluetooth .

Comment: Thank you for your answer but nothing happend.