# Bluetooth not working on lenovo g50-30 (Ubuntu 15.10)

Tags: bluetooth, 15.10, lenovo

Problem above.
If you need any more information feel free to ask me.

```
movioli@movioli-Lenovo-G50-30:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 105b:e065 Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth module
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:579a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
movioli@movioli-Lenovo-G50-30:~$ rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
movioli@movioli-Lenovo-G50-30:~$  dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
movioli@movioli-Lenovo-G50-30:~$ uname -a
Linux movioli-Lenovo-G50-30 4.2.0-25-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 12:31:50 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
movioli@movioli-Lenovo-G50-30:~$ hciconfig -a
movioli@movioli-Lenovo-G50-30:~$
```

After trying the tutorial mentioned in the comments below

movioli@movioli-Lenovo-G50-30:~$     sudo cp ~/BCM.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm

movioli@movioli-Lenovo-G50-30:~$ sudo service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sa 2016-01-30 19:49:59 CET; 16min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 638 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─638 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working on ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu)

Comment: In addition you will need to install this package https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/bluetooth/+files/btusb-bcm105b-dkms_0.1_all.deb

Comment: After following this steps+installing  the package you´ve mentioned, i´m still getting no bluetooth signal,although i get this (see post)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the firmware installation, you need to install a kernel module. Run

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/bluetooth/+files/btusb-bcm105b-dkms_0.1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install btusb-bcm105b-dkms_0.1_all.deb
```

Then reboot.

Comment: after several restarts it bluetooth is now working. thank you guys