# bluetooth devices not showing in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, broadcom

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and windows 8.1 dual boot. And in my ubuntu OS I got Bluetooth installed in it. I wanted to connect my bluetooth device, like my phone, my bluetooth headphones etc. But it does not list the any of available bluetooth devices.Why? and what i also experienced is the devices were visible in ubuntu if i turn off all the network connection(go to airplane mode) in windows 8.1 and turn it back on in ubuntu. Can a get a permanent solution too see my bluetooth devices visible in ubuntu Every time I try to do so? 
thanks in advance. looking for serious help

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working on ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Do not post screenshots copy text from terminal.

Answer (score -2):

Try Blueman

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

Comment: not a good solution. already tried it. now after my firmware update, i have got my device connected but is not listed in audio output menu. why? any solutions?