# Toshiba Broadcom bluetooth [0930:0225] is not working on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, toshiba

i can't enable bluetooth.

I have tried every things but no success, Here is some commands i have tried:

```
$> rfkill list  

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

also :

```
⋊> ~ dmesg | grep tooth                                                                                                                   
[   11.482503] toshiba_bluetooth: Detected Toshiba ACPI Bluetooth device - installing RFKill handler
[   11.482532] toshiba_bluetooth: Re-enabling Toshiba Bluetooth
[   18.098091] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[   18.098114] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   18.098120] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   18.098123] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   18.098129] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   18.126202] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   18.126212] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   18.126219] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   19.170244] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   19.170253] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   19.170265] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

and :

```
⋊> ~ sudo /etc/rc.d/bluetooth restart                                                                                                     
sudo: /etc/rc.d/bluetooth: command not found

⋊> ~ hcitool scan                                                                                                                         
Device is not available: No such device

⋊> ~ hciconfig hci0 piscan                                                                                                                
Can't get device info: No such device

⋊> ~ hciconfig -a                                                                                                                         

⋊> ~ sudo hciconfig hci0 reset                                                                                                            
Can't get device info: No such device

⋊> ~ sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth 

⋊> ~ lsusb                                                                                                                                10:55:54
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 13d3:5652 IMC Networks 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0930:0225 Toshiba Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f3:0362 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

⋊> ~ uname -r                                                                                                                             10:55:57
3.19.0-37-generic

⋊> ~ sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily                                                                                          10:58:52
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Les paquets suivants ont été installés automatiquement et ne sont plus nécessaires :
  gdm gir1.2-gkbd-3.0 gir1.2-xkl-1.0 gnome-control-center-data kde-l10n-engb
  kde-l10n-fr libcamel-1.2-45 libcolord-gtk1 libgdata13 libgeocode-glib0
  libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libossp-uuid16 libt1-5 linux-headers-3.19.0-25
  linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic linux-headers-3.19.0-32
  linux-headers-3.19.0-32-generic linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic
  linux-image-3.19.0-32-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-32-generic linux-signed-image-3.19.0-32-generic
Veuillez utiliser « apt-get autoremove » pour les supprimer.
Les paquets supplémentaires suivants seront installés : 
  linux-headers-4.2.0-30 linux-headers-4.2.0-30-generic
  linux-headers-generic-lts-wily linux-image-4.2.0-30-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-30-generic linux-image-generic-lts-wily
Paquets suggérés :
  fdutils linux-lts-wily-tools
Les NOUVEAUX paquets suivants seront installés :
  linux-generic-lts-wily linux-headers-4.2.0-30 linux-headers-4.2.0-30-generic
  linux-headers-generic-lts-wily linux-image-4.2.0-30-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-30-generic linux-image-generic-lts-wily
0 mis à jour, 7 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 258 non mis à jour.
Il est nécessaire de prendre 65,8 Mo dans les archives.
Après cette opération, 295 Mo d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n] O
Réception de : 1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-image-4.2.0-30-generic amd64 4.2.0-30.36~14.04.1 [17,2 MB]
Réception de : 2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-image-extra-4.2.0-30-generic amd64 4.2.0-30.36~14.04.1 [38,3 MB]
Réception de : 3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-image-generic-lts-wily amd64 4.2.0.30.24 [2 270 B]
Réception de : 4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-headers-4.2.0-30 all 4.2.0-30.36~14.04.1 [9 593 kB]
Réception de : 5 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-headers-4.2.0-30-generic amd64 4.2.0-30.36~14.04.1 [779 kB]
Réception de : 6 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-headers-generic-lts-wily amd64 4.2.0.30.24 [2 246 B]
Réception de : 7 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-generic-lts-wily amd64 4.2.0.30.24 [1 798 B]
65,8 Mo réceptionnés en 1min 50s (597 ko/s)                                    
Sélection du paquet linux-image-4.2.0-30-generic précédemment désélectionné.
(Lecture de la base de données... 453096 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Préparation du décompactage de .../linux-image-4.2.0-30-generic_4.2.0-30.36~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Décompactage de linux-image-4.2.0-30-generic (4.2.0-30.36~14.04.1) ...
Sélection du paquet linux-image-extra-4.2.0-30-generic précédemment désélectionné.
Préparation du décompactage de .../linux-image-extra-4.2.0-30-generic_4.2.0-30.36~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Décompactage de linux-image-extra-4.2.0-30-generic (4.2.0-30.36~14.04.1) ...
Sélection du paquet linux-image-generic-lts-wily précédemment désélectionné.
Préparation du décompactage de .../linux-image-generic-lts-wily_4.2.0.30.24_amd64.deb ...
Décompactage de linux-image-generic-lts-wily (4.2.0.30.24) ...
Sélection du paquet linux-headers-4.2.0-30 précédemment désélectionné.
Préparation du décompactage de .../linux-headers-4.2.0-30_4.2.0-30.36~14.04.1_all.deb ...
Décompactage de linux-headers-4.2.0-30 (4.2.0-30.36~14.04.1) ...
Sélection du paquet linux-headers-4.2.0-30-generic précédemment désélectionné.
Préparation du décompactage de .../linux-headers-4.2.0-30-generic_4.2.0-30.36~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Décompactage de linux-headers-4.2.0-30-generic (4.2.0-30.36~14.04.1) ...
Sélection du paquet linux-headers-generic-lts-wily précédemment désélectionné.
Préparation du décompactage de .../linux-headers-generic-lts-wily_4.2.0.30.24_amd64.deb ...
Décompactage de linux-headers-generic-lts-wily (4.2.0.30.24) ...
Sélection du paquet linux-generic-lts-wily précédemment désélectionné.
Préparation du décompactage de .../linux-generic-lts-wily_4.2.0.30.24_amd64.deb ...
Décompactage de linux-generic-lts-wily (4.2.0.30.24) ...
Paramétrage de linux-image-4.2.0-30-generic (4.2.0-30.36~14.04.1) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.2.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.2.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-30-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.2.0-30-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.248+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.2.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-30-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.2.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.2.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.2.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-30-generic
Création du fichier de configuration GRUB…
Attention : Définir GRUB_TIMEOUT à une valeur non nulle si GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT est définie n’est plus possible.
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-30-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-30-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-37-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-37-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-33-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-33-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-32-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-32-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-25-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-25-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
fait
Paramétrage de linux-image-extra-4.2.0-30-generic (4.2.0-30.36~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.2.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.2.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-30-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/bcmwl-kernel-source.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.2.0-30-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.248+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.2.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-30-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.2.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.2.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.2.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-30-generic
Création du fichier de configuration GRUB…
Attention : Définir GRUB_TIMEOUT à une valeur non nulle si GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT est définie n’est plus possible.
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-30-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-30-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-37-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-37-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-33-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-33-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-32-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-32-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-25-generic
Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-25-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
fait
Paramétrage de linux-image-generic-lts-wily (4.2.0.30.24) ...
Paramétrage de linux-headers-4.2.0-30 (4.2.0-30.36~14.04.1) ...
Paramétrage de linux-headers-4.2.0-30-generic (4.2.0-30.36~14.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.2.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-30-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/bcmwl-kernel-source.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.2.0-30-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.248+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
Paramétrage de linux-headers-generic-lts-wily (4.2.0.30.24) ...
Paramétrage de linux-generic-lts-wily (4.2.0.30.24) ...
```

And :

```
⋊> ~ dmesg | grep -i blue                                                                                                                 14:16:25
[   16.351486] toshiba_bluetooth: Toshiba ACPI Bluetooth device driver
[   17.296782] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[   17.296814] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   17.296820] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   17.296824] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   17.296840] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   19.955916] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   20.891741] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   20.891752] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   20.891759] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   20.966313] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   20.966318] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   20.966324] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   27.953430] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)
[  162.983131] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[  162.983138] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[  163.756152] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0217
[  525.946630] Modules linked in: cmac bnep rfcomm binfmt_misc intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_codec_hdmi coretemp snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core kvm_intel snd_hwdep uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc kvm snd_pcm videobuf2_memops snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event videobuf2_core btusb wl(POE) v4l2_common snd_rawmidi btrtl videodev btbcm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer btintel media hid_multitouch bluetooth rtsx_pci_ms snd soundcore toshiba_acpi cryptd memstick cfg80211 sparse_keymap input_leds i915 joydev serio_raw wmi toshiba_bluetooth mei_me drm_kms_helper drm mei i2c_algo_bit shpchp lpc_ich parport_pc ppdev lp video parport mac_hid rtsx_pci_sdmmc hid_generic psmouse ahci libahci rtsx_pci usbhid r8169 hid mii
```

this is the result :

[clic to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oItIT.png)

Some one can help ? Thank's

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb; uname -r` terminal command.

Comment: You can see results in the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support of Toshiba Broadcom based bluetooth devices [has been recently added](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-wily.git/commit/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c?id=ba494aab55f3de0c10eb1602c902af01ad979910) to Ubuntu 4.2 kernel.

To get it work on your system you need to upgrade the kernel by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

if you do not have 4.2 kernel already.

You may have errors with compiling of `bcmwl-kernel-source`. In this case install an updated version of this driver by

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb
```

Then reboot. This way you will keep your Wi-Fi working.

After that you will need to install Broadcom firmware according to [this manual](https://askubuntu.com/a/632348/167850).

Your bluetooth device is

```
0930:0225 Toshiba Corp.
```

P.S. For kernels 3.19 the patch has been [committed too](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-vivid.git/commit/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c?h=master-next&id=b7c15064766b1ca1be0b3909afaa2e54da952288). The kernel image is in the `proposed` repository and soon will get into the main repositories.