# Bluetooth headset Issue on 16.04

Tags: bluetooth, 16.04, asus, headset

I have recently upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04. My bluetooth headset no longer works. I've spent the last few hours trying to diagnose the issue with no success. My bluetooth mouse still connects ok.

```
Headset: Plantronics backbeat pro
USB Dongle: Asus - Broadcom BCM20702A0
```

I had a small issue with 14.04 where I had to include "Disable=headset" in `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` however it seems that this file is no longer accessed in the latest bluez/pulse audio arrangement.

I've tried purge removing bluetooth, pulseaudio and bluez and reinstalling with no success. Any help would be appreciated

journalctl logs on connection of usb dongle:

```
May 04 19:09:31  kernel: usb 3-4: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
May 04 19:09:31  kernel: usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0b05, idProduct=17cb
May 04 19:09:31  kernel: usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
May 04 19:09:31  kernel: usb 3-4: Product: BCM20702A0
May 04 19:09:31  kernel: usb 3-4: Manufacturer: Broadcom Corp
May 04 19:09:31  kernel: usb 3-4: SerialNumber: 5CF3706C6DB1
May 04 19:09:31  URfkill[924]: adding killswitch type 2 idx 1 soft 0 hard 0
May 04 19:09:31  URfkill[924]: Setting device 1 (BLUETOOTH) to unblocked
May 04 19:09:31  URfkill[924]: set_soft: Setting BLUETOOTH to unblocked
May 04 19:09:31  mtp-probe[5353]: checking bus 3, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:05:00.0/usb3/3-4"
May 04 19:09:31  kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
May 04 19:09:31  mtp-probe[5353]: bus: 3, device: 4 was not an MTP device
May 04 19:09:31  kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A
May 04 19:09:31  kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
May 04 19:09:31  kernel: bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0b05-17cb.hcd failed with error -2
May 04 19:09:31  kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0b05-17cb.hcd not found
May 04 19:09:31  bluetoothd[4595]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
May 04 19:09:31  bluetoothd[4595]: Not enough free handles to register service
May 04 19:09:31  bluetoothd[4595]: Error adding Link Loss service
May 04 19:09:31  bluetoothd[4595]: Not enough free handles to register service
May 04 19:09:31  bluetoothd[4595]: Not enough free handles to register service
May 04 19:09:31  bluetoothd[4595]: Not enough free handles to register service
May 04 19:09:31  bluetoothd[4595]: Current Time Service could not be registered
May 04 19:09:31  bluetoothd[4595]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
May 04 19:09:31  bluetoothd[4595]: Not enough free handles to register service
May 04 19:09:31  bluetoothd[4595]: Not enough free handles to register service
May 04 19:09:31  bluetoothd[4595]: Sap driver initialization failed.
May 04 19:09:31  bluetoothd[4595]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
```

*****If I try and connect to the headset I receive the following errors:

```
May 04 19:01:14  bluetoothd[1180]: Unable to get connect data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
May 04 19:01:14  bluetoothd[1180]: connect error: Too many levels of symbolic links (40)
May 04 19:01:14  bluetoothd[1180]: GLib: Source ID 212 was not found when attempting to remove it
May 04 19:01:16  bluetoothd[1180]: connect error: Too many levels of symbolic links (40)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working on ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

You can download required file from [here](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware).

Locate it in `brcm/BCM20702A1-0b05-17cb.hcd` and place it into `/lib/firmware/brcm/BCM20702A1-0b05-17cb.hcd`. After that just re-insert bluetooth device. `dmesg` will show you that firmware properly loaded, so you can configure bluetooth with Bluez software.

Comment: Thanks for response, installed the firmware file and I also use this script to connect properly to the bluetooth device

https://gist.github.com/pylover/d68be364adac5f946887b85e6ed6e7ae

Answer (score 1):

The crux of the issue is this:

> ```
> May 04 19:09:31 kernel: bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for
> brcm/BCM20702A1-0b05-17cb.hcd failed with error -2
> ```

Your configuration is not right for this bluetooth adapter so the firmware that it needs will not run. Without the firmware its just silicon, it needs code to run it properly, that is the firmware.

[This link](https://launchpad.net/bcm20702a1/+download) should have the right firmware but it's not packaged for ubuntus beyond Oneiric so you will need to put it in `/lib/firmware/brcm/` yourself