# Ubuntu 16.04 bluetooth adapter doesn't search

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, bluetooth, broadcom

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04, then installed `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` on it.

I'm unable to use the bluetooth. I have selected the broadcom driver to use from "Additional Drivers" section.

The wifi works, but not bluetooth.

Moreover, the bluetooth settings screen shows `Visible as "Bastien's Computer"`... I didnt give that name!

I installed "Bluetooth Manager" and "Bluetooth Adapter" (Blueman) from Softwares, but still nothing. The adapter doesn't show up in there.

It just keeps searching and doesn't find anything. Doesn't show up on other devices.

**sudo service bluetooth status**

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-05-11 13:25:17 IST; 23min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 998 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─998 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

May 11 13:25:17 dushyant-3543 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
May 11 13:25:17 dushyant-3543 bluetoothd[998]: Bluetooth daemon 5.37
May 11 13:25:17 dushyant-3543 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
May 11 13:25:17 dushyant-3543 bluetoothd[998]: Starting SDP server
May 11 13:25:17 dushyant-3543 bluetoothd[998]: Bluetooth management interface 1.10 initialized
```

**lsusb**
`Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working on ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu)

Comment: @Pilot6 , I'm downloading the firmware now... lets see.
btw, it used to work fine on 15.10

Comment: @Pilot6, I followed the steps, but its not working. HOWEVER, not it shows  by pc-name instead of `Bastien's Computer`. Blueman shows adapter as "ChromeLinux_3B4B". NOTE: This has happened before too, when I installed Blueman.

Comment: @Pilot6, I rebooted again, we're back to `Bastien's Computer` now :|

Comment: @Pilot6, can i get it from ubuntu 14.04 or 15.10? because it used to work in those. Even in their live USBs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following commands remove and add the bluetooth module:

```
rmmod btusb
modprobe btusb
```

After that, I can see the bluetooth devices.
Sadly, I need to do this after every reboot.

Moreover, my bluetooth headset connects but the sound is not received.

So I have to switch the sound profile to A2DP, then test sound. When it does not come, I switch back to whatever other profile is.

After that, fire the above commands.

Then connect the headset again, switch to A2DP profile.
The headset starts working! "Front Left" " Front Right" she says when I click on test sound :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue on a HP Stream 11 laptop. A temporary solution for my laptop is to turn aeroplane mode on and off.

A hard solution for resetting your wirless chip on start up would be to add these lines to the end of your .bashrc:

```
nmcli networking off 
nmcli networking on
```

Comment: naah, tried airplane mode too many times, restarts. can you explain the `.bashrc` thing?

Comment: No, i've tried airplane mode a lot of times :(