# Who is Bastien?

Tags: bluetooth

After a fresh installation of Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.1 and after installing all updates, upgrading to 16.04.2, I have a strange issue with Bluetooth.

If I turn Bluetooth on, it reports in Bluetooth pane of GNOME Settings:

> Visible as "Bastien's computer" and available for Bluetooth file transfers.

Who is Bastien?

Bastien, if you read this, could you please comment and explain why Bluetooth thinks that my computer is yours?

Moreover, my Bluetooth does not see any other Bluetooth, and is not seen by any other Bluetooth.

This issue has been reported before, without a satisfactory explanation:

- [Ubuntu 16.04 bluetooth adapter doesn't search](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770188/ubuntu-16-04-bluetooth-adapter-doesnt-search)
- https://forum.manjaro.org/t/bluetooth-issue-visible-as-bastiens-computer/4994

Comment: Did you download the iso from an official source?

Comment: I followed links from http://ubuntugnome.org/.

Comment: Found a bug report for it https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1571262

Comment: Sounds like a translator left their name in one of the strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow lots of bug reports on "Bastien's Computer" being in peoples' bluetooth settings. It turns out you can talk to Bastien himself in this bug report: [Visible as “Bastien Nocera's Computer”](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=755967).

The common solution is to use:

```
rfkill list
```

and search for:

```
#: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
```

Then use:

```
rfkill unblock #
```

Where `#` is a number like `0`, `1`, `3` or `6`.

If this doesn't solve it or, it only lasts for a single session, you can find other tips from Bastien in the link above.