# BCM43602 - bluetooth not working - sees device MAC but won't pair

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, broadcom

This is a new XPS 15 9550 with the BCM43602 (14e4:43ba), and I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. When I try to use the standard bluetooth manager, it searches and finds a device with a MAC (but doesn't display a name), but it the "next" box is greyed out. I also tried using Blueman to pair the device, and it failed. I tried trusting it and then pairing it, and it failed. Not sure what to do.

The bluetooth device in question is a Microsoft Sculpt Comfort Mouse, and it works on my other Ubuntu laptop.

If I need to supply more info, please let me know. I am generally capable with Linux, but kernel modules/drivers has be kind of confused.

`uname -a; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware; lsmod | grep bluetooth`

returns

```
Linux teamamerica 4.4.0-22-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 12 22:03:46 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [1028:0024]
    Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:21d5 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:6410 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1532:0034 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:6713 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    3.290211] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    3.290224] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.290227] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.290229] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.290233] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.296135] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    3.296137] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    3.296138] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    3.296139] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    3.296140] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    3.296141] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    3.296166] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    3.296183] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
[    3.296184] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    3.333662] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 102
[    3.350343] Bluetooth: hci0: ChromeLinux_8456
[    3.351658] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.005) build 0000
[    3.352116] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd failed with error -2
[    3.352118] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd not found
[    4.357144] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.357146] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.357149] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    7.003113] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    7.003118] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    7.003122] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    0.227661] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    3.352116] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd failed with error -2
[    3.527691] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[    4.009107] brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Nov 10 2015 06:38:10 version 7.35.177.61 (r598657) FWID 01-ea662a8c
bluetooth             520192  31 bnep,btbcm,btqca,btrtl,btusb,hci_uart,rfcomm,btintel
```

and

`sudo service bluetooth status`

returns

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-05-25 06:48:45 CDT; 23min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 918 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─918 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

May 25 07:10:38 teamamerica bluetoothd[918]: Not enough free handles to register service
May 25 07:10:38 teamamerica bluetoothd[918]: Not enough free handles to register service
May 25 07:10:38 teamamerica bluetoothd[918]: Current Time Service could not be registered
May 25 07:10:38 teamamerica bluetoothd[918]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
May 25 07:10:38 teamamerica bluetoothd[918]: Not enough free handles to register service
May 25 07:10:38 teamamerica bluetoothd[918]: Not enough free handles to register service
May 25 07:10:38 teamamerica bluetoothd[918]: Sap driver initialization failed.
May 25 07:10:38 teamamerica bluetoothd[918]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
May 25 07:10:38 teamamerica bluetoothd[918]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.95 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
May 25 07:10:38 teamamerica bluetoothd[918]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.95 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
~
~
~
~
```

Comment: First uninstall wl with `sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source` and reboot

Comment: Won't that command also turn off the wifi @Jeremy31 ?

Comment: @morhook it shouldn't in this case as it is using a brcmfmac module for wifi.  It seems the asker edited the question to remove info about using bcmwl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working on ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, you can install the firmware file that is failing on line

```
[    3.352116] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd failed with error -2
[    3.352118] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd not found
```

Download from https://www.dropbox.com/s/8goc4omhnzxij93/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd?dl=0 the missing firmware and create a file like /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd (all this suggested from https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=204739 and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2317843)

**Update:**
Another version (v481) might be working better: http://ubuntuforums.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=269987&d=1467804097 , also you'll need to put the file in /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd