# bluetooth headset not discovered by ubuntu 16.04. discovered easily by windows 10 on the same machine

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headset

I am posting this as my last step before giving up completely on making my Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop recognize my bluetooth headset.

I have followed all the other questions and answers regarding this with no luck, the Bluetooth adapter in my laptop is obviously capable of finding this headset as it works perfectly from windows.

both blueman and the regular bluetooth manager show a lot of unnamed devices (only by address) all of them are of type "all types" and they are all unpairable (pairing fails after a few seconds, doesn't look like anything is really happening there).

On my Android device, the address of the bluetooth headset is listed as "**00:11:67:B4:A4:DF**". none of the recognized devices have this address.

Output from `sudo service bluetooth status` :

```
bluetoothd[1274]: Not enough free handles to register service
bluetoothd[1274]: Sap driver initialization failed.
bluetoothd[1274]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
bluetoothd[1274]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.48 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
bluetoothd[1274]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.48 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
bluetoothd[1274]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.84 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
bluetoothd[1274]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.84 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
bluetoothd[1274]: RFCOMM server failed for Headset Voice gateway: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
bluetoothd[1274]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.48 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
bluetoothd[1274]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.48 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```

Output from `bluetoothctl` :

```
[NEW] Controller 48:E2:44:F5:E9:6E yaniv-XPS [default]
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 48:E2:44:F5:E9:6E Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device 54:79:7A:A9:F1:58 54-79-7A-A9-F1-58
[NEW] Device 62:D2:69:E6:51:4C 62-D2-69-E6-51-4C
[NEW] Device 76:53:BC:C4:D9:9E 76-53-BC-C4-D9-9E
[NEW] Device 5E:8D:79:7D:91:28 5E-8D-79-7D-91-28
[NEW] Device 79:E3:D4:8C:18:E1 79-E3-D4-8C-18-E1
[NEW] Device 98:01:A7:9B:19:5A 98-01-A7-9B-19-5A
[CHG] Device 79:E3:D4:8C:18:E1 RSSI: -97
[CHG] Device 76:53:BC:C4:D9:9E RSSI: -97
[CHG] Device 79:E3:D4:8C:18:E1 RSSI: -82
[CHG] Device 62:D2:69:E6:51:4C RSSI: -69
[NEW] Device F8:77:B8:1D:16:74 F8-77-B8-1D-16-74
[CHG] Device 98:01:A7:9B:19:5A RSSI: -80
[CHG] Device 62:D2:69:E6:51:4C RSSI: -93
[CHG] Device 79:E3:D4:8C:18:E1 RSSI: -93
[CHG] Device 98:01:A7:9B:19:5A RSSI: -92
```

Output from `dmesg | grep -i blue`

```
Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 102
Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20703A1
Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.005) build 0000
bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd failed with error -2
Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd not found
Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Any help on this matter would be highly appreciated!
Thanks ahead.

Comment: Have you checked if your headset is compatible with Ubuntu? There are os many headset that only works for windows, can you say your headset model?

Comment: My laptop's adapter supports it, there are no OS specifications on the headphones model. it's a JBL E25BT

Comment: Can you send info about your bluetooth controller? I'm reading that there are some fails with some controllers on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I was struggling with that a bit. Is there a command or something that shows me that information?

Comment: @Jeremy31 [That's not](http://www.adminsub.net/mac-address-finder/broadcom) a Broadcom MAC address

Comment: @Fabby Yaniv is missing firmware for the broadcom bluetooth as seen `Patch brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd not found` although Pilot6's linked driver may not have this ID.  A better answer is [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/789533/300665) but it hasn't been upvoted or accepted

Comment: @Jeremy31 if the answer is good, why haven't you upvoted it yourself?