# Bluetooth not working on Acer Aspire E3-112 or with Bluetooth dongle

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

I have an acer Aspire E3-112 which has internal Bluetooth ... I am unable to get it working ... it seems the only drivers available are for Windows.  So I inserted a logitech USB Bluetooth dongle; now Ubuntu 14 is able to 'see' the device (my iphone 5) sometimes, but even with Ubuntu finding the device the connect function is greyed out.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks - Trenton

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e07e]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b469 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 03f0:094a Hewlett-Packard Optical Mouse [672662-001]
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0489:e055 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I downloaded the Windows driver and found the following:
%Dell1704.DeviceDesc%=RAMUSB21D7,           USB\VID_0A5C&PID_21D7       ; BRCM Generic 43142A0 RAMUSB

I can not find the *.hex file that the other posting is asking for.  Please help.

Just found it ... following further directions from previous question now.

how do i "Now extract that firmware from the same cab file." ??

I am a newbie, sorry for any extra effort .. I am following the directions in the other post.

I found the file BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0197.0229.hex ... what does it mean when the instructions say "Now extract that firmware from the same cab file."?

I believe I have done all the steps in the preceeding issue ... here are some commands I saved to make sure I did it correct:
%BtUSB.DeviceDesc%=BlueRAMUSBE055,              USB\VID_0489&PID_E055       ; 43142A0 Acer combo

BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0197.0229.hex

[RAMUSB21D7.CopyList]
bcbtums.sys
btwampfl.sys
BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0197.0229.hex

BCM43142A0-0489-e055.hcd

Static hostname: trenton-Aspire-E3-112
         Icon name: computer-laptop
           Chassis: laptop
           Boot ID: 7b81a386a0d54481ad37b6d5203ef622
  Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 4.2.0-42-generic
      Architecture: i686

sudo cp BCM43142A0-0489-e055.BCM.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm

Does that look correct?

BCM43142A0-0489-e055.BCM.hcd is that wrong?

Comment: Let's try to get the internal one working. Remove the dongle, then [edit] your question and post output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: What commands shall I insert into this forum for you to know more?

Comment: The one I posted is good enough to start with.

Comment: Your BT device is `0489:e055 Foxconn / Hon Hai `. You need to install firmware.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working on ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Check your kernel version by `uname -a` to give the correct name to the firmware file.

Comment: You need to find firmware for YOUR adapter, not `0a5c:21d7`, but `0489:e055`. I thought it was clear enough.

Comment: Extract means take out this file from the cab and copy it somewhere.

Comment: It does not look correct. For kernel 4.2 the name of the file should be `BCM.hcd`.

Comment: Rename the file `BCM43142A0-0489-e055.hcd` to `BCM.hcd` and do `sudo cp BCM.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm`.

Comment: It is better to ask these things in comments. Yes `BCM43142A0-0489-e055.BCM.hcd` is wrong. There is no such name in the manual.

Comment: I did the rename of the .hcd file to BCM43142A0-0489-e055.BCM.hcd and did sudo cp BCM43142A0-0489-e055.BCM.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm

Comment: Why don't you do what I tell you? Why did you rename it to `BCM43142A0-0489-e055.BCM.hcd`, when I told you to rename it to `BCM.hcd`? Where did you get this `BCM43142A0-0489-e055.BCM.hcd`? It is nonsense.

Comment: I got it connected! Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: Even though the iphone shows up as connected I can not move files to/from it ... any reason why this would happen?

Comment: I was thinking it would show up as another HDD on my Acer Aspire E3-112?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right about BCM43142A0 device. I think you take incorrect *.hex file. You can find required firmware from here - https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware . Make sure that you placed *.hcd to /lib/firmware/brcm. After that re-insert BT device or just reboot.