# wifi and bluetooth not working in hp model 15-ac054TU

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

**`lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network` output:**

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 255
    Region 0: Memory at 91200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
```

**`iwconfig` output:**

```
lo         no wireless extensions.

enp3s0 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; no wireless extensions.
```

**`lspci -knn | grep net -A2` output:**

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:80c5]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

---

I think my system is Ubuntu 16.04, but I think I don't have the right driver.  I don't understand what to check with regards to my model number and specifications to determine what drivers I need to install.

Neither wifi or Bluetooth work on my computer, can someone help me fix this please?

Comment: What is the result of these terminal commands? `sudo modprobe wl` and also: lsmod | grep -e wl -e b43` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot for Wi-Fi. See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/632348/167850) for BT.

Comment: @chili555 When `wl` is there and not in use, that means that Secure Boot is on.

Comment: m in office tell you at night please be online at night

Comment: the result is nothing after run  "sudo modprobe wl"  this and secure boot is off

Comment: still wifi show but doesn't clickable

Comment: now after typing rfkill list it shows

Comment: 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes

Comment: can you help me

Answer (score -1):

Search for "additional drivers" in All applications and then enable the proprietry drivers for your wifi. This will enable your default wifi.

Comment: They are already installed.

Comment: I enable all the property but not work

Comment: any idea how to resolve this problem.. how to enable wifi and bluetooth??