# Bluetooth can't detect devices 16.04

Tags: drivers, 16.04, sound, bluetooth

I am using Ubuntu **16.04 Lts** on my Sony Vaio.

**I want to connect to my Bluetooth Headphone?**

[image]

Graphical UI keeps on serching but never finds any bluethooh devices.

**sudo rfkill list**

```
0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
    1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    2: nfc0: NFC
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    3: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
    4: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: yes
    7: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

**hciconfig -a**

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: B5:87:3E:EE:FF:FE  PQT MTU: 1071:8  SCO MTU: 24:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN INQUIRY 
    RX bytes:2881 acl:0 sco:0 events:211 errors:0
    TX bytes:3620 apl:0 sdo:0 commands:241 errors:0
    Features: 0xef 0xee 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DH1 DH3 DQ5 DH1 DR3 DH5 HR1 HE2 HE3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'ChromeLinux_D188'
    Class: 0x0c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x0
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x210b
    Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)
```

**hcitool scan**

```
Scanning ...
```

What is probably wrong with bluethooth device?

Thanks..!

**lspci -knn | grep Net -A2**

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [105b:e071]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

**lsusb**

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0489:e062 Foxconn / Hon Hai
```

**usb-devices | awk '/0489/' RS=**

```
usb-devices | awk '/0489/' RS= 
T: Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=02 Dev#= 7 Spd=12 MxCh= 0 
D: Ver= 2.00 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs= 1 
P: Vendor=0489 ProdID=e062 Rev=01.12 
S: Manufacturer=Broadcom Corp 
S: Product=BCM43142A0 
S: SerialNumber=XXXXXXXXXXXX 
C: #Ifs= 4 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA 
I: If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb 
I: If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb 
I: If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=btusb 
I: If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=fe(app. ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working on ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu)

Comment: @Pilot6 Please check output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

Comment: It looks like this device is not in the kernel yet. Please add output of `usb-devices`. I need to identify the BT adapter. Then I will be able to fix it. I do not really need the full output. You can cut only devices 2 to 4.

Comment: I suspect it is the Foxconn. `usb-devices | awk '/0459/' RS=`

Comment: I do not need `lsusb` again. I need `usb-devices | awk '/0459/' RS=`

Comment: @Pilot6 please check output of `usb-devices`

Comment: It is weird. Do you type that manually?  I see different numbers. Is it `0459:e112 Foxconn / Hon Hai` or `0489:e112 Foxconn / Hon Hai`?

Comment: @Pilot6 please see output of `usb-devices | awk '/0459/' RS` in edit  3

Comment: It is weird too. Is it `0459`, or `0489`? It should be same in `lsusb` and `usb-devices`.

Comment: @Pilot6 its long editing. Their can be typo. Please ignore it.

Comment: Please do not type it manually. Copy text from terminal and paste it here. You can remove incorrect output of `lsusb`. It is important.

Comment: And both your `usb-devices` have different IDs and serial numbers. Are they from one computer?

Comment: @Pilot6 Sure. Thaks for ur assistance. What is be the probable fault.

Comment: I will tell you after you post a reliable output. Now it looks like crap.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43914/discussion-between-pcp-and-pilot6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem with the same adapter, I managed to solve by following the instructions of that response:[Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working)