# Bluetooth on Lenovo B590 with 16.04 not working

Tags: bluetooth

Wanting to give my Lenovo B590 new life, I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it. However, Bluetooth does not work at all anymore; indeed, running `lsusb` yields

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b2fa Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:2007 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 03f0:304a Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 03f0:134a Hewlett-Packard Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

As you see, the built-in 
Broadcom Bluetooth 4.­0 is not detected at all, hence I could not follow [this other guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/632348/467037). None of the other guides I have found helped much, either; many were technical and aimed at older versions of Ubuntu or were not useful for other reasons. **How can I get Bluetooth working?** Complete step-by-step guides are *very* welcome and might be awarded.

**Update:** As requested in the comments, I provide the output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`:

```
[   11.251690] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is unblocked
[   13.116194] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   13.116209] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   13.116212] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   13.116213] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   13.116217] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   15.247647] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   23.242930] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)
[   25.250793] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   33.246178] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)
[   34.984665] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   34.984668] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   34.984672] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: You can run `usb-devices` and find which one is your BT device. I suspect `04ca:2007`. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, it seems you are right. :-) And then that guide should work?

Comment: Correct. Now use that guide. BTW my answer has the information on how to find out which device is the BT, if it is not stated in `lsusb`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working on ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu)

Comment: @Pilot6 By the way, my laptop runs 64 bit. So I assume I should look into `bcbtums-win8x64-brcm.inf` instead of the one with `86` in it?

Comment: It does not matter at all. You just find the name of a firmware file you need there.

Comment: I followed the guide very precisely, and it has *not* worked. The same problem is still there; I don’t find anything when I search for devices, even though my mobile has BT turned on and is lying right next to it.

Comment: How did you call the hcd firmware file? It should be `BCM.hcd` for your Ubuntu version. You can see what happens in `dmesg | grep -i blue`.

Comment: But running `uname -r`, I get `4.4.0-34-generic`. Thus according to your guide, I should call it `BCM-04ca-2007.hcd`. Anyway, see my (in a moment) updated answer for the output of `dmesg ...`.

Comment: They change it in the kernel all the time. Probably `BCM.hcd` will do. Rename it. If it works, I will fix it there too.

Comment: Oops. You have  `BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)`. That should be reported as a bug. It is not a firmware issue.

Comment: Can it be because earlier, I tried removing `bluez` and installing it again using `apt-get`?

Comment: It is not a user space problem. It is a kernel one. Installed soft is not related.

Comment: But anyway, it works now that I renamed the file `BCM.hcd` and turned my PC off and on again. Thanks!

Comment: I will fix it in my answer. I suspected that someone installed some newer kernel that 4.4. They changed it again there.