# Bluetooth device not working after patch

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, broadcom

My broadcom bluetooth device was not working so I followed the solution posted on the following link:
[Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu)

I downloaded the latest driver from broadcom, found the file i needed, converted it to hcd and used the name BCM.hcd after checking my dmesg log. Now my bluetooth device is not even starting. I am getting the following messages on my dmesg log:

```
[   22.040870] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)

[   24.049006] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
```

lsusb still recognises my bluetooth device

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
```

Also, I removed the file I had pasted into /lib/firmware/brcm earlier. Now, the dmesg log shows the following messages:

```
[   23.867936] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout

[   31.863859] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)

[   32.062376] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3

[   32.062378] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast

[   32.062382] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: This looks like some bug. What is the kernel version?

Comment: Is kernel version the OS version? If so then it is 16.04

Comment: Kernel version is not the OS version, but in 16.04 it should be 4.4. You can see it by `uname -r`. Are you sure you converted the correct file to hcd?

Comment: I converted a file for this adapter. https://www.dropbox.com/s/bsowlvv3f9my7kj/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd?dl=0 For kernel 4.4 you need to rename it to `BCM.hcd`.

Comment: I named it BCM.hcd before copying it.  Also, I would suggest an edit to your previous answer.  In the new version of the driver, the .inf file is not named bcbtums-win8x86-brcm.inf. Instead, it is named bcbtums.inf

Comment: It does not really matter how the inf file is called.

Comment: Also, I tried both the driver you posted and also the latest one from broadcomm. Both show the same results

Comment: Try the file I posted now. If it still does not work, report a bug.

Comment: It does not work. I will report the bug. Thanks for your help