# Bluetoothctl can't find default device but hciconfig / hcitool can see my device

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I was using BlueZ-5.49 at Linux with HCI-UART controller (Nordic Zephyr project).

I already use btattach to connect with my adapter and can do scan through hcitool.

```
$ hciconfig -a
@ RAW Open: hciconfig (privileged) version 2.22             {0x0003} 240.238053
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: UART
        BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 27:7  SCO MTU: 0:0
        UP RUNNING
        RX bytes:476 acl:0 sco:0 events:34 errors:0
        TX bytes:248 acl:0 sco:0 commands:34 errors:0
        Features: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x60 0x00 0x00 0x00
        Packet type: DM1 DH1 HV1
        Link policy:
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
```

I would like to use `bluetoothctl` to connect my peripherals
but I cannot find my adapter

```
$bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]#                         Agent registered
[bluetooth]# list
[bluetooth]# scan on
No default controller available
```

It seems that the `bluetoothctl` does not recognize this adapter.

I think my issue is similar to the below question. However, I don't quite understand what was the solution is.

[bluetoothctl can't detect device but hcitool can?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835084/bluetoothctl-cant-detect-device-but-hcitool-can?newreg=263e1d1c4d3c4abb8438252712e74c15)

I hope someone could give me some hint to check what's missing on my system right now.

Thank for your help.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Answer (score 0):

BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 - that's not a good sign. Looks like a driver issue.

I have the same problem with what appears to be a counterfeit CSR dongle. rmmod btusb && modprobe btusb helped reset the BD Address to a real one, however bluetoothctl still doesn't see it:

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:1A:XX:XX:XX:11  ACL MTU: 679:9  SCO MTU: 48:16
    UP RUNNING 
    RX bytes:1140 acl:0 sco:0 events:58 errors:0
    TX bytes:702 acl:0 sco:0 commands:59 errors:1
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0xcd 0xfa 0xdb 0xbf 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: ''
    Class: 0x000000
    Service Classes: Unspecified
    Device Class: Miscellaneous, 
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x810
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x810
    Manufacturer: Cambridge Silicon Radio (10)
```

I had to recompile my kernel to do some changes in the btusb.c otherwise it would not even bring up the interface.

Here's my USB device information from dmesg:
idVendor=0a12, idProduct=0001, bcdDevice=88.91