# Bluetooth not working on Xubuntu 16.04 Thinkpad x230

Tags: bluetooth, thinkpad, bluez, x230

I just made a fresh installation of Xubuntu 16.10 on my Lenovo Thinkpad x230. Almost everything works perfectly except for the Bluetooth. In previous editions of Xubuntu the bluetooth has worked with this computer.  When I try to launch the bluetooth manager I get an error message that says:

> Bluez daemon is not running, blueman-manager cannot continue.

After running `lsusb` I get the following output:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b2ea Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera [ThinkPad]  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root
```

There is no bluetooth device showing up here. In other forum posts about this problem, a device from Broadcom shows up. It seems the Thinkpad x230 should use the drivers for: **Broadcom Corporation BCM20702 Bluetooth 4.0**

I have tried to install drivers for this by following the following forum-thread without any results:

- [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu)

Does anyone have any ideas what I can do?