# How come my Bluetooth wont get enabled?

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to connect a Surface Air Mouse to my computer. But as you can see below my Bluetooth settings won't get enabled. Need help enabling it. It says Bluetooth: on but on the next line it says Bluetooth is disabled

Click here to see what it looks like:
[Bluetooth Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mylAj.jpg)

Comment: What's the output of `sudo rfkill list`?

Comment: `0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working on ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu)