# Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS Could not find any bluetooth device(while it is recognized)

Tags: bluetooth, broadcom

I'm new to Linux.

When I try to use my built-in bluetooth chipset in Huawei Matebook, the adapter seems recognized well but it could not find any bluetooth device.

I also try to use bluetooth with my dongle type adapter and then it is working

here is my `hciconfig -a`

```
~$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
BD Address: FC:3F:7C:63:81:35  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
UP RUNNING 
RX bytes:2068 acl:0 sco:0 events:116 errors:0
TX bytes:3865 acl:0 sco:0 commands:113 errors:0
Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
Name: 'yeomMate'
Class: 0x0c010c
Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing
Device Class: Computer, Laptop
HCI Version: 4.1 (0x7)  Revision: 0x2000
LMP Version: 4.1 (0x7)  Subversion: 0x230f
Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)
```

I wonder why it say that Bus type is USB.

and `dmesg |grep [bB]luetooth` is here

```
$ dmesg |grep [bB]luetooth
[    3.276981] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    3.277036] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.277040] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.277042] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.277063] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.300552] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 101
[    3.316606] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM4354A2
[    3.317586] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM4354A2 (001.003.015) build 0000
[    3.317608] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM4354A2-0a5c-6419.hcd failed with error -2
[    3.317611] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM4354A2-0a5c-6419.hcd not found
[    4.329100] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.329104] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.329109] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    8.713237] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    8.713246] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    8.713254] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

my working usb-type bluetooth also fail to Direct firmware load. but it works.

nothing is blocked in `rfkill list`

if you want any other info,
I will be glad to append

Comment: The name of your `.hcd` file should be `BCM4354A2-0a5c-6419.hcd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download Windows BT drivers from Huawei site

http://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/tablets/huawei_matebook_en-sup.htm

You will need to press "load more" a couple of times  to see it.

Then use [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/632348/167850) to convert and install the firmware.

The name of your `.hcd` file should be `BCM4354A2-0a5c-6419.hcd`.

Comment: It works for me!
Even my bluetooth device has delay, but works well
Thank you Pilot6.