# Logitech M557 does not pair with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mouse, bluetooth, logitech

My Logitech M557 bluetooth mouse does not pair with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I opened the Bluetooth settings window of Ubuntu, which indicates that Bluetooth is "On".  I selected the "+" button to start the Device Search for all device types.  I turned on the power switch of the M557 mouse and then pressed the "pair" button, which starts its blue pairing light to blink.  The M557 is not found by the search.

I changed the device type to "Input devices" in the Device Search window, but the result is no better.

Also, I attempted to pair a JBL speaker, and that did not work.  Bose headphones do not pair either.  I also changed the "Visibility" switch for the computer in the Bluetooth settings window, which did not help.

The computer is a Dell Inspiron 15.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

===== as requested additional information ====

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:5756 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:0084 Microsoft Corp. Basic Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working/632348#632348

Comment: That Broadcom firmware update solution was CRAZY NUTS to follow, but **it worked!!!**  I actually paired a new Logitech M535 mouse, rather than the mouse that started with, but either way it is solved!  Much much thanks Pilot6!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, the mouse device did not appear in the list of Bluetooth devices.
Then I followed mindtab advice to press a button to make the device discoverable.

SO I pressed the button in the mouse device for a few seconds and then the mouse appeared in the list. Then I connected to it from the list of devices, and it then WORKED FINE.

Comment: Lol, you were right

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install solaar

That's for the Logitech mouse.

As far as the JBL speaker, it may have a button on it with a bluetooth icon; press and hold for a few seconds to make the device discoverable. (some bose speakers have that)

Comment: Solaar is for the Logitech **Unifying receiver** that plugs into the USB port.  My Logitech mouse is **Bluetooth**.