# Bluetooth BCM20702A1 not working - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, usb, bluetooth, broadcom

The bluetooth service is running, but it is not working. I have tried [this steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working/632348) for BCM20702A1 (ID 105b:e066) but it didn't work. I noticed on my `usb-devices` that the product is listed as Broadcom BCM20702A0, but on `lsusb` it shows 105b:e066 Foxconn International, Inc.

> service bluetooth status

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-07-04 12:38:10 ACST; 3min 21s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 6373 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─6373 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jul 04 12:38:10 robson-vb systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jul 04 12:38:10 robson-vb bluetoothd[6373]: Bluetooth daemon 5.37
Jul 04 12:38:10 robson-vb systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jul 04 12:38:10 robson-vb bluetoothd[6373]: Starting SDP server
Jul 04 12:38:10 robson-vb bluetoothd[6373]: Bluetooth management interface 1.13
```

> lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 105b:e066 Foxconn International, Inc.
```

> usb-devices

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=105b ProdID=e066 Rev=01.12
S:  Manufacturer=Broadcom Corp
S:  Product=BCM20702A0
S:  SerialNumber=342387DAE35E
C:  #Ifs= 4 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=fe(app. ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
```

> dmesg | grep -i blue

```
[  140.529665] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[  140.529689] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  140.529692] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  140.529695] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  140.529702] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  140.875501] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  140.875502] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  140.875506] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

> dmesg | grep -i BCM

```
[    3.063962] usb 1-1.1: Product: BCM20702A0
[    8.099294] wlan0: Broadcom BCM4359 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.271 (r587334)
```

> uname -a

```
Linux robson-vb 4.8.0-58-generic #63~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 18:08:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What kernel are you using- `uname -a`

Comment: Hi Jeremy, 
`Linux robson-vb 4.8.0-58-generic #63~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 18:08:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Can you file a bug report at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs that will help get a permanent fix in the kernel.  Pilot6 has already committed a fix to the Linux kernel but I think Ubuntu likes to see a bug report before they will include anything new in 4.4 or 4.8/4.10 kernels

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-4.8.git
cd bluetooth-4.8
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/.config ./
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo depmod -a
```

Reboot and see if it works

After a kernel update the steps will need to be done again

```
cd bluetooth-4.8
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) clean
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/.config ./
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo depmod -a
```

Reboot

Comment: Hey Jeremy, thanks for the reply. It didn't work, there was an error: `sudo cp btusb /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/`
`cp: cannot stat 'btusb': No such file or directory
`

Comment: I realized you meant the file  btusb.ko. It works like a charm now. Thanks

Comment: @Jeremy31 Did you send the patch upstream?

Comment: I see that it is not there. Will you send it?

Comment: This repository appears to be gone though there are some newer ones associated with that same user. Will it work to use https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-5.15 instead? (I got a build error) In my case, I installed the firmware package for my device from here: https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/releases