# Bluetooth issue on 16.04 with BCM43142

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, hp

I am super stuck with this bluetooth issue. I've tried everything explained here [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working/632348#632348)

Managed to find the matching BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0122.0156.hex file for my BCM43142 14e4:4365 
I have followed all those steps and still bluetooth isn't working.
I got Ubuntu 16.04.03 running on a HP Stream Notebook.I'm not super versed in Linux but I'm still able to follow instructions I don't know what the problem is here. Thanks for you help.

```
gaelle@gaelle-HP-Stream-Notebook:~$ dmesg | grep Blue
[    9.454746] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    9.454775] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    9.454781] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    9.454785] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    9.454793] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    9.742287] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[    9.758301] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[    9.758305] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[   11.829505] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0a0a tx timeout
[   13.461403] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   13.461406] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   13.461412] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   19.956921] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch command 0a0a failed (-110)
[   22.100927] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   30.197421] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)
[   32.309441] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   40.437122] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)

~$ uname -a
Linux gaelle-HP-Stream-Notebook 4.10.0-28-generic #32~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 20 10:19:48 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

gaelle@gaelle-HP-Stream-Notebook:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:216d Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:57c4 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

gaelle@gaelle-HP-Stream-Notebook:~$ lsusb Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:216d Broadcom Corp. Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:57c4 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

gaelle@gaelle-HP-Stream-Notebook:~$ dmesg | grep -i blue [ 10.165216] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22 [ 10.165243] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized [ 10.165249] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized [ 10.165253] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized [ 10.165261] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized [ 10.320063] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70 [ 10.337010] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A [ 10.337015] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000 [ 12.432007] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0a0a tx timeout [ 14.500911] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3 [ 14.500914] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast [ 14.500921] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized [ 20.464553] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch command 0a0a failed (-110) [ 22.576493] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout [ 30.704009] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110) [ 32.796226] Modules linked in: bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nls_iso8859_1 hp_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl intel_soc_dts_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd intel_cstate wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm uvcvideo btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_soc_rt5670 bluetooth snd_soc_rt5645 videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core snd_soc_rt5640 videodev snd_intel_sst_acpi snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_sst_match cfg80211 input_leds snd_soc_core media snd_compress joydev ac97_bus serio_raw snd_pcm_dmaengine rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi memstick snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core snd_hwdep lpc_ich snd_pcm snd_rawmidi shpchp mei_txe mei [ 32.817093] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout [ 40.948496] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110) [ 52.361086] Modules linked in: bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nls_iso8859_1 hp_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl intel_soc_dts_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd intel_cstate wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm uvcvideo btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_soc_rt5670 bluetooth snd_soc_rt5645 videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core snd_soc_rt5640 videodev snd_intel_sst_acpi snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_sst_match cfg80211 input_leds snd_soc_core media snd_compress joydev ac97_bus serio_raw snd_pcm_dmaengine rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi memstick snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core snd_hwdep lpc_ich snd_pcm snd_rawmidi shpchp mei_txe mei [ 60.148197] Modules linked in: bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nls_iso8859_1 hp_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl intel_soc_dts_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd intel_cstate wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm uvcvideo btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_soc_rt5670 bluetooth snd_soc_rt5645 videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core snd_soc_rt5640 videodev snd_intel_sst_acpi snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_sst_match cfg80211 input_leds snd_soc_core media snd_compress joydev ac97_bus serio_raw snd_pcm_dmaengine rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi memstick snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core snd_hwdep lpc_ich snd_pcm snd_rawmidi shpchp mei_txe mei [ 67.625544] Modules linked in: bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nls_iso8859_1 hp_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl intel_soc_dts_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd intel_cstate wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm uvcvideo btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_soc_rt5670 bluetooth snd_soc_rt5645 videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core snd_soc_rt5640 videodev snd_intel_sst_acpi snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_sst_match cfg80211 input_leds snd_soc_core media snd_compress joydev ac97_bus serio_raw snd_pcm_dmaengine rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi memstick snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core snd_hwdep lpc_ich snd_pcm snd_rawmidi shpchp mei_txe mei [ 75.720350] Modules linked in: bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nls_iso8859_1 hp_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl intel_soc_dts_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd intel_cstate wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm uvcvideo btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_soc_rt5670 bluetooth snd_soc_rt5645 videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core snd_soc_rt5640 videodev snd_intel_sst_acpi snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_sst_match cfg80211 input_leds snd_soc_core media snd_compress joydev ac97_bus serio_raw snd_pcm_dmaengine rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi memstick snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core snd_hwdep lpc_ich snd_pcm snd_rawmidi shpchp mei_txe mei [ 80.533487] Modules linked in: bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nls_iso8859_1 hp_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl intel_soc_dts_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd intel_cstate wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm uvcvideo btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_soc_rt5670 bluetooth snd_soc_rt5645 videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core snd_soc_rt5640 videodev snd_intel_sst_acpi snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_sst_match cfg80211 input_leds snd_soc_core media snd_compress joydev ac97_bus serio_raw snd_pcm_dmaengine rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi memstick snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core snd_hwdep lpc_ich snd_pcm snd_rawmidi shpchp mei_txe mei [ 89.036146] Modules linked in: bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nls_iso8859_1 hp_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl intel_soc_dts_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd intel_cstate wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm uvcvideo btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_soc_rt5670 bluetooth snd_soc_rt5645 videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core snd_soc_rt5640 videodev snd_intel_sst_acpi snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_sst_match cfg80211 input_leds snd_soc_core media snd_compress joydev ac97_bus serio_raw snd_pcm_dmaengine rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi memstick snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core snd_hwdep lpc_ich snd_pcm snd_rawmidi shpchp mei_txe mei [ 97.232251] Modules linked in: bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nls_iso8859_1 hp_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl intel_soc_dts_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd intel_cstate wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm uvcvideo btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_soc_rt5670 bluetooth snd_soc_rt5645 videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core snd_soc_rt5640 videodev snd_intel_sst_acpi snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_sst_match cfg80211 input_leds snd_soc_core media snd_compress joydev ac97_bus serio_raw snd_pcm_dmaengine rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi memstick snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core snd_hwdep lpc_ich snd_pcm snd_rawmidi shpchp mei_txe mei [ 102.356984] Modules linked in: bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nls_iso8859_1 hp_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl intel_soc_dts_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd intel_cstate wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm uvcvideo btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_soc_rt5670 bluetooth snd_soc_rt5645 videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core snd_soc_rt5640 videodev snd_intel_sst_acpi snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_sst_match cfg80211 input_leds snd_soc_core media snd_compress joydev ac97_bus serio_raw snd_pcm_dmaengine rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi memstick snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core snd_hwdep lpc_ich snd_pcm snd_rawmidi shpchp mei_txe mei [ 112.600725] Modules linked in: bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nls_iso8859_1 hp_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl intel_soc_dts_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd intel_cstate wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm uvcvideo btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_soc_rt5670 bluetooth snd_soc_rt5645 videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core snd_soc_rt5640 videodev snd_intel_sst_acpi snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_sst_match cfg80211 input_leds snd_soc_core media snd_compress joydev ac97_bus serio_raw snd_pcm_dmaengine rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi memstick snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core snd_hwdep lpc_ich snd_pcm snd_rawmidi shpchp mei_txe mei [ 120.796675] Modules linked in: bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nls_iso8859_1 hp_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl intel_soc_dts_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd intel_cstate wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm uvcvideo btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_soc_rt5670 bluetooth snd_soc_rt5645 videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core snd_soc_rt5640 videodev snd_intel_sst_acpi snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_sst_match cfg80211 input_leds snd_soc_core media snd_compress joydev ac97_bus serio_raw snd_pcm_dmaengine rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi memstick snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core snd_hwdep lpc_ich snd_pcm snd_rawmidi shpchp mei_txe mei [ 128.988664] Modules linked in: bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nls_iso8859_1 hp_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl intel_soc_dts_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd intel_cstate wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm uvcvideo btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_soc_rt5670 bluetooth snd_soc_rt5645 videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core snd_soc_rt5640 videodev snd_intel_sst_acpi snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_sst_match cfg80211 input_leds snd_soc_core media snd_compress joydev ac97_bus serio_raw snd_pcm_dmaengine rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi memstick snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core snd_hwdep lpc_ich snd_pcm snd_rawmidi shpchp mei_txe mei [ 134.112416] Modules linked in: bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nls_iso8859_1 hp_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl intel_soc_dts_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd intel_cstate wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm uvcvideo btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_soc_rt5670 bluetooth snd_soc_rt5645 videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core snd_soc_rt5640 videodev snd_intel_sst_acpi snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_sst_match cfg80211 input_leds snd_soc_core media snd_compress joydev ac97_bus serio_raw snd_pcm_dmaengine rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi memstick snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core snd_hwdep lpc_ich snd_pcm snd_rawmidi shpchp mei_txe mei [ 142.308797] Modules linked in: bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nls_iso8859_1 hp_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl intel_soc_dts_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd intel_cstate wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm uvcvideo btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_soc_rt5670 bluetooth snd_soc_rt5645 videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core snd_soc_rt5640 videodev snd_intel_sst_acpi snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_sst_match cfg80211 input_leds snd_soc_core media snd_compress joydev ac97_bus serio_raw snd_pcm_dmaengine rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi memstick snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core snd_hwdep lpc_ich snd_pcm snd_rawmidi shpchp mei_txe mei [ 150.501680] Modules linked in: bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nls_iso8859_1 hp_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl intel_soc_dts_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd intel_cstate wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm uvcvideo btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_soc_rt5670 bluetooth snd_soc_rt5645 videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core snd_soc_rt5640 videodev snd_intel_sst_acpi snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_sst_match cfg80211 input_leds snd_soc_core media snd_compress joydev ac97_bus serio_raw snd_pcm_dmaengine rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi memstick snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core snd_hwdep lpc_ich snd_pcm snd_rawmidi shpchp mei_txe mei [ 159.108627] Modules linked in: bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nls_iso8859_1 hp_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl intel_soc_dts_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd intel_cstate wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm uvcvideo btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_soc_rt5670 bluetooth snd_soc_rt5645 videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core snd_soc_rt5640 videodev snd_intel_sst_acpi snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_sst_match cfg80211 input_leds snd_soc_core media snd_compress joydev ac97_bus serio_raw snd_pcm_dmaengine rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi memstick snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core snd_hwdep lpc_ich snd_pcm snd_rawmidi shpchp mei_txe mei [ 167.304472] Modules linked in: bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nls_iso8859_1 hp_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl intel_soc_dts_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd intel_cstate wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm uvcvideo btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_soc_rt5670 bluetooth snd_soc_rt5645 videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core snd_soc_rt5640 videodev snd_intel_sst_acpi snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_sst_match cfg80211 input_leds snd_soc_core media snd_compress joydev ac97_bus serio_raw snd_pcm_dmaengine rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi memstick snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core snd_hwdep lpc_ich snd_pcm snd_rawmidi shpchp mei_txe mei [ 170.952714] Modules linked in: bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nls_iso8859_1 hp_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl intel_soc_dts_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd intel_cstate wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm uvcvideo btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_soc_rt5670 bluetooth snd_soc_rt5645 videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core snd_soc_rt5640 videodev snd_intel_sst_acpi snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_sst_match cfg80211 input_leds snd_soc_core media snd_compress joydev ac97_bus serio_raw snd_pcm_dmaengine rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi memstick snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core snd_hwdep lpc_ich snd_pcm snd_rawmidi shpchp mei_txe mei [ 179.596977] Modules linked in: bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nls_iso8859_1 hp_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl intel_soc_dts_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd intel_cstate wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm uvcvideo btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_soc_rt5670 bluetooth snd_soc_rt5645 videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core snd_soc_rt5640 videodev snd_intel_sst_acpi snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_sst_match cfg80211 input_leds snd_soc_core media snd_compress joydev ac97_bus serio_raw snd_pcm_dmaengine rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi memstick snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core snd_hwdep lpc_ich snd_pcm snd_rawmidi shpchp mei_txe mei
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dmesg | grep Blue` terminal command.

Comment: What is the kernel version `uname -a`?

Comment: This is either a bug, or you converted a wrong firmware file.

Comment: It's very difficult to find the firmware file, but according to my research it's supposed to be the .hex file mentioned above. That I downloaded from the drivers of another pc, maybe that's the problem. Or maybe I'm not entering the commands properly, this is where my lack of expertise comes into play...

Comment: What is the device `lsusb`? Did you ever check it? What was your "research"?

Comment: hope this helps

Comment: Can you format your posts yourself?

Comment: According to my "research" the file is `BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0311.0329.hex`

Comment: Ok, and thanks a lot this has been driving me nuts... can you tell me where to find the file and what exact commands to perform in terminal for my kernel version please.

Comment: The commands were given in the answer you've read.

Comment: I know but there were several ones for different kernel versions and that's got me quite confused...

Comment: It looks like you did it correctly.

Comment: I did it again and it still doesn't work... check out the dmesg | grep Blue log above :(

Comment: I can't read your edit. Please format it properly using the `{}` button.

Comment: I'm sorry I thought you could see it... I just added {} at the beginning and end of the post. I'm not sure that's what I have to do, I'm sure you're busy and appreciate the help, but your instructions are a bit vague lol anyway, I found another .hex as you suggested and still it didn't work...

Comment: You need to select the output and PRESS THE `{}` BUTTON. It doesn't mean to add `{` or `}` symbols to the text. I've formatted your output twice. You can do it yourself.

Comment: I just did it but i don't know if it worked sorry I never use this kind of thing...

Comment: Any chance of getting an update on this I'm still stuck...

Comment: Report a bug to Launchpad.