# Blueman-manager can't detect devices Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: blueman

**I have installed blueman and all dependencies, but in the blueman-manager app I can not find any device, any idea?**

*System Information*

> Manufacturer: Sony Corporation
>   Product Name: SVF1521C4E
>   Version: C10J0PTJ
>   Serial Number: 54610130-0001219
>   UUID: EC5205E0-53E9-11E2-B221-78843C3BB4B0
>   Wake-up Type: Power Switch
>   SKU Number: 54610130
>   Family: VAIO

*lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; hciconfig -a*

> 07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
>   Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [105b:e071]
>   Kernel driver in use: wl
>   Kernel modules: wl
>   0e:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.   >RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
>   Subsystem: Sony Corporation RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit >Ethernet   Controller [104d:90b8]
>   Kernel driver in use: r8169
>   Kernel modules: r8169
>   Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
>   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>   Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:0543 Acer, Inc
>   Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e062 Foxconn / Hon Hai
>   Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
>   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>   Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
>   Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>   [    1.668163] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
>   [   11.244719] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
>   [   11.244734] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
>   [   11.244737] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
>   [   11.244739] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
>   [   11.244743] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
>   [   11.601936] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
>   [   11.617939] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
>   [   11.617941] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
>   [   11.677603] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed   >with error -2
>   [   11.677612] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
>   [   13.683789] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
>   [   23.065495] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
>   [   23.065497] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
>   [   23.065499] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
>   [   90.059428] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
>   [   90.059436] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
>   [   90.059444] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
>   hci0:  Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
>   BD Address: 0C:84:DC:F5:61:00  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
>   UP RUNNING
>   RX bytes:986 acl:0 sco:0 events:54 errors:0
>   TX bytes:3653 acl:0 sco:0 commands:54 errors:0
>   Features: 0xff 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
>   Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3
>   Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF
>   Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
>   Name: 'ricciolino_bluetooth'
>   Class: 0x10010c
>   Service Classes: Object Transfer
>   Device Class: Computer, Laptop
>   HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x0
>   LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x210b
>   Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)

*hcitool dev*

> Devices:
>
> > hci0  0C:84:DC:F5:61:00

*rfkill list*

> 0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
>   Soft blocked: no
>   Hard blocked: no
>   1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
>   Soft blocked: no
>   Hard blocked: no
>   2: phy0: Wireless LAN
>   Soft blocked: no
>   Hard blocked: no
>   3: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
>   Soft blocked: no
>   Hard blocked: no
>   4: hci0: Bluetooth
>   Soft blocked: no
>   Hard blocked: no

**resolved following [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working) guide, the problem was the bcm43142 driver**

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; hciconfig -a`

Comment: Please update your post with the following information: you hardware (laptop/desktop model, Bluetooth adapter model), output of `hcitool dev`,  `rfkill list`.