# How can I uninstall my Bluetooth driver 16.04? I installed it using hex2hcd method

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, broadcom, firmware

I installed my Bluetooth driver with the best answer to this question [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working) but after I installed my Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 firmware using hex2hcd method to install the firmware, my Broadcom 43142 802.11/b/g/n firmware conflicts with it each other.

My question is how can I uninstall my Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 or how can I revert it back to the normal (primarily I don't have the firmware of my Bluetooth before) again.

After running

```
dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
```

Here's the firmware that I want to uninstall.

```
[   26.584896] Bluetooth: hci0: Broadcom 43142 Bluetooth 4.0 Adapter
```

But I don't know how to uninstall it because I installed it using the hex2hcd method then pasting the `.hcd` file in the `/lib/firmware/brcm`.

---

UPDATE:
For now, I use

```
systemctl disable bluetooth
```

to disable the Bluetooth on startup so that I can use my WiFi.

But I still need to uninstall that Bluetooth firmware...

Answer (score 1):

I would blacklist the btusb module and reboot

```
echo "blacklist btusb" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

If you want to use bluetooth then just `sudo modprobe btusb`