# Broadcom BCM43242A0 Bluetooth adapter not detected in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bluetooth, 18.04, broadcom

My Laptop has a Broadcom BCM43242A0 Bluetooth adapter  which does not work with Kubuntu 18.04.

```
lsusb | grep Bluetooth 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth Device
```

I already tried to fix it by downloading the firmware from
https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/tree/master/brcm
and copied it to /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM.hcd because the output of

```
dmesg | grep bluetooth
```

was

```
[ 12.314809] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
```

After that, the bluetooth adapter is not recognised anymore in the system settings -> Bluetooth and `dmesg | grep bluetooth` gives no return.
Output of

```
uname -r; lsusb; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; rfkill list all; hciconfig -a; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
```

is

```
4.15.0-22-generic
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth Device
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b40e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Truevision HD camera
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c00c Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:2230]
        Kernel driver in use: wl
--
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 08)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [103c:2297]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
        DOWN 
        RX bytes:312 acl:0 sco:0 events:7 errors:0
        TX bytes:37 acl:0 sco:0 commands:9 errors:0
        Features: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
        Packet type: DM1 DH1 HV1 
        Link policy: 
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 

[    0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x25 (or later)
[    0.049786] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.167623] [Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (0)
[    2.822033] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PXSX) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[   21.550566] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
[   21.611269] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   21.611297] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   21.611302] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   21.611306] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   21.611316] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   21.749781] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   21.750785] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[   21.766795] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[   21.766798] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[   23.900113] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0a0a tx timeout
[   27.050123] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   27.050125] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   27.050128] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   31.964068] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch command 0a0a failed (-110)
[   34.076050] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   42.204067] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)
```

I have no Idea what this means, but from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1483101 I understood that this bug has been fixed with a newer linux kernel. My kernel version is 4.15.0-22-generic, but the problem still persist. How can I get bluetooth working?

Comment: What exact file did you grab from the winterheart github?

Comment: I downloaded BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd.

Comment: P.S. With Ubuntu 14.04, bluetooth wasn't working either, but after downloading the firmware it at least recognised a bluetooth headset, but could not pair with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working)

Answer (score 6):

**Steps to fix:**

1. Go to repo [winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/tree/master/brcm) and download file
   [BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/raw/master/brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd) (according your Bluetooth chipset).
2. Move that file to `/lib/firmware/brcm` (if not working: rename file to `BCM.hcd`)
3. Turn off and turn on pc

**P.S.** This can work for other **broadcom** adapters as well, only need to get correct `.hcd` file: grep **Bluetooth Device** and **ID** with command `lsusb | grep Bluetooth`.

**Edited** This Bluetooth issue solution working for Ubuntu 20.04 as well.

> Source https://dev-pages.info/ubuntu-bluetooth/

Comment: Naming it `BCM.hcd` didn't work in my case as the error message indicates it is looking for a specific file name (ex. "Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd..."), so download and copy as-is to `/lib/firmware/brcm` should be fine.

Comment: Correct But you don't have to turn off the PC, retart the Bluetooth works, Here is the steps `sudo modprobe -r btusb` and then `sudo modprobe btusb`

Comment: This worked finally.
WOW, I forgot the feeling of a working bluetooth device on my Linux machine.
Thanks!
p.s: I needed to rename the file to `BCM.hcd`

Answer (score 0):

After 5 days of trying I finally got it to work for me.

What I did is firstly I deleted all of the .hcd files from /lib/firmware/brcm (used  sudo nautilus file manager) then very important to download the correct files from given link.

Go to repo winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware and download the file BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd (according your Bluetooth chip-set).

Move that file to /lib/firmware/brcm (if not working: rename file to BCM.hcd) very important.

P.S. This can work for other broadcom adapters as well, only need to get the correct .hcd file: grep Bluetooth Device and ID with command lsusb | grep Bluetooth.

After downloading the .hcd file I copied it to /lib/firmware/brcm using this command :sudo cp BCM20702A0-0a5c-216f.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm (need to change hcd file name according what you download).

After this i restart my Bluetooth service using this command.

sudo modprobe -r btusb and then sudo modprobe btusb

That is it everything works now.

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1170589)