# bluetooth is not visible

Tags: bluetooth

Im a new user to ubuntu and just installed ubuntu today.

when i try to connect my bluetooth headphones with my laptop it is unable to find any device even my mobile phone can not find my laptop's bluetooth name. kindly help me solve this problem

Comment: First check bluetooth is turned on in your bios. Then open system settings and type bluetooth in the search bar. Check that it is turned on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working)