# Bluetooth cannot find device (Ubuntu 16.04 Bluetooth: RFCOMM)

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

I have faced a problem that my desktop Bluetooth cannot find any devices.

When I run Bluetooth status, I got below errors:

```
#sudo service Bluetooth status

● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-04-19 23:44:21 CST; 5min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 809 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─809 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Apr 19 23:44:21 liu-K401UQ bluetoothd[809]: Not enough free handles to register service
Apr 19 23:44:21 liu-K401UQ bluetoothd[809]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Apr 19 23:44:21 liu-K401UQ bluetoothd[809]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Apr 19 23:44:25 liu-K401UQ bluetoothd[809]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Apr 19 23:44:25 liu-K401UQ bluetoothd[809]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Apr 19 23:44:31 liu-K401UQ bluetoothd[809]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.69 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Apr 19 23:44:31 liu-K401UQ bluetoothd[809]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.69 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Apr 19 23:44:31 liu-K401UQ bluetoothd[809]: RFCOMM server failed for Headset Voice gateway: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
Apr 19 23:44:48 liu-K401UQ bluetoothd[809]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Apr 19 23:44:48 liu-K401UQ bluetoothd[809]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```

For Bluetooth device information

```
$ lsusb; rfkill list; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 13d3:3487 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:57ed Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c084 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 24ae:4005  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
[    0.054904] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.235227] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.791522] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    2.791542] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.791640] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.791643] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.791650] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.891379] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.891383] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.891387] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    8.368496] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    8.368502] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    8.368507] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

And I have already download BCM.hcd and place it into folder according to the solution: [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working/632348#632348), but still cannot fix my problem.

Hope anyone can help me, thanks a lot!