# Ubuntu 16.04 VMware - Bluetooth unable to connect

Tags: 16.04, drivers, bluetooth

I've been using VMware which claims to have HID support, [however I am unable to connect to my device as the connect switch is greyed out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L0Gf.png) (My host OS is macOS Sierra.) I tried using the command-line `bluetoothctl`, but it claims the device is unavailable.

```
drivers@ubuntu:~$ bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller 78:4F:43:96:5D:53 ubuntu [default]
[NEW] Device 00:1E:35:77:43:03 Nintendo RVL-CNT-01
[bluetooth]# info 00:1E:35:77:43:03
Device 00:1E:35:77:43:03
    Name: Nintendo RVL-CNT-01
    Alias: Nintendo RVL-CNT-01
    Class: 0x002504
    Icon: input-gaming
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: no
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Service Discovery Serve.. (00001000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v057Ep0306d0600

[bluetooth]# connect 00:1E:35:77:43:03
Attempting to connect to 00:1E:35:77:43:03
[CHG] Device 00:1E:35:77:43:03 Connected: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable
[CHG] Device 00:1E:35:77:43:03 Connected: no

[bluetooth]# quit
[DEL] Controller 78:4F:43:96:5D:53 ubuntu [default]
```

Many threads that I've found ask for the output to `lsusb`. Oddly enough, the `lsusb` output does not even mention bluetooth anywhere! According to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working), the culprit is installing firmware for broadcom, but I have already done that.

```
drivers@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0008 VMware, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: You need to understand what a VM is, what hardware parts are and aren't available to the guest, what can be made available and how. Tutorials and answers about hardware issues in a real installation AREN'T applicable.

Comment: And it's very unlikely you'll be able to use the integrated Bluetooth in the guest. You may get lucky with a USB one with the proper setting in VMWare.