# Jerky Bluetooth, music is playing irregularly

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, broadcom

I was not able to detect Bluetooth devices on my Toshiba Satellite, I followed this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/985016/974073). I am now able to connect to bluetooth devices but when I play music it is jerky and lags, sometimes it even disconnects.

Here is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: XAVi Technologies Corp. BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [1b9a:3002]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

As my chip cannot be found on the github given in the answer I used this driver :
`BCM43142A0-0930-0225.hcd`
because `dmesg | grep -i 'firmware load'` was mentionning this version.

Is there a way to correct this issue ?

Output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b446 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 0930:0225 Toshiba Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 045e:07fd Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver 1.1
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: What does `lsusb` show?

Comment: @Pilot6 I updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely that this problem can be fixed, because bluetooth share the same 2.4 GHz band with Wi-Fi. And Broadcom proprietary driver doesn't have an option to toggle wireless coexistence. But you can try.

The github repo is 3 years old. You can try to find more recent Windows drivers and get firmware from there.

See [THIS ANSWER](https://askubuntu.com/a/632348/167850) for instructions. Links to Windows drivers may be old too, but you can search for some more recent bundle, or extract the firmware from an installed Windows system.

Comment: You are right for the first part of your answer, when I desactivate the wifi it is not jerky anymore. Will try the rest of your answer.

Comment: If you are unsuccessful, I can suggest to change the wireless adapter to something else.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! What do you mean by something else ?

Comment: Some other built-in wireless adapter. You can buy and replace it, if your laptop BIOS doesn't have a whitelist. This will fix the BT and enable 5GHz wireless band. QCA or Intel work well on linux.

Comment: So I have been unsuccessful finding a newer driver, at least I know what is going on and how to prevent it from happening with my current configuration. Will be attentive to the wifi adapter next time I buy a laptop !