# Bluetooth problem in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: bluetooth, 19.04, dell-vostro

Bluetooth in my [Dell Vostro 1550 laptop](http://dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/vostro-1550/overview) ([hardware manual](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_vostro_notebook/vostro-1550_service%20manual_en-us.pdf)) sees no nearby device; all it does the search for nearby devices. I have the option to turn it off or on. All it does is:

Bluetooth setting screen after I turn on Bluetooth (this goes on for eternity)
[image: Bluetooth setting screen after I turn on Bluetooth: image]

After running the command: `sudo rfkill && lspci`
[image: the terminal after running the command]

After running the command : `sudo rfkill && lspci`

```
prakul@metalhead-vostro-1550:~$ subl
prakul@metalhead-vostro-1550:~$ sudo rfkill list && lspci
[sudo] password for prakul: 
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Mobile SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
09:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
prakul@metalhead-vostro-1550:~$ ^C
prakul@metalhead-vostro-1550:~$ ^C
prakul@metalhead-vostro-1550:~$
```

Comment: If you're on a desktop you might need to connect an antenna.

Comment: Please run `sudo rfkill list && lspci` in a terminal, copy the results, then come back here, click [edit] and paste them in. Please do not use Add Comment; use [edit] instead. Editing tips are at https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code . Also see https://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-bluetooth-in-linux/

Comment: @prk_27 Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy text from a terminal and paste it as text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working)