# How to make bluetooth audio work with Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: drivers, sound, bluetooth, 19.10, bluez

Inspired by [this article](https://www.nielsvandermolen.com/bluetooth-headphones-ubuntu/) I tried to use my Samsung U Flex bluetooth headsets but I failed. It is not shown in the list of available devices although the headphones are put in the pairing mode and the Ubuntu installation is from yesterday with the latest updates:

```
silviu@silviu-Inspiron-3537:~$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth # Shows all Bluetooth driver info
[    5.187807] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.190266] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.190272] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.190274] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.190280] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.330031] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[    5.331042] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[    5.453051] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[    5.454037] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[    5.455166] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd failed with error -2
[    5.455169] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd not found
[    7.141810] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    7.141812] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    7.141815] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    7.474343] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[    7.476034] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[  124.727177] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  124.727182] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  124.727187] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  227.915239] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[  227.916078] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
silviu@silviu-Inspiron-3537:~$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth | grep -i firmware # Shows Bluetooth firmware issues
[    5.455166] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd failed with error -2
silviu@silviu-Inspiron-3537:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:58c2 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c53f Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04e8:61f5 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Portable SSD T5
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

In the `bluetoothctl` command I get:

```
[bluetooth]# scan on
Failed to start discovery: org.bluez.Error.NotReady

[bluetooth]# devices
Device 00:E0:4C:A1:71:30 SoundCore mini
```

(This is another device to which I cannot connect to play music.)

(After a reboot, this:

```
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller F8:2F:A8:DE:8E:4E Discovering: yes
```

but still no devices found (only SoundCore would have been visible anyway).)

Then

```
[bluetooth]# pair 00:E0:4C:A1:71:30 
Attempting to pair with 00:E0:4C:A1:71:30
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed
```

The blueman package won't make it work, it does not show an error in the user interface.

```
silviu@silviu-Inspiron-3537:~$ pactl list | grep -i bluetooth # Shows if Bluetooth modules are loaded
    Nume: module-bluetooth-policy
        module.description = "Policy module to make using bluetooth devices out-of-the-box easier"
    Nume: module-bluetooth-discover
        module.description = "Detect available Bluetooth daemon and load the corresponding discovery module"
        module.description = "Detect available BlueZ 5 Bluetooth audio devices and load BlueZ 5 Bluetooth audio drivers"
```

Please note that normal audio (through jack) works pretty well.

Thank you.

## Update 1

The driver worked well, I could hear the local music player. After one or two reboots, the device does not work well:

The driver is loaded:

```
silviu@silviu-Inspiron-3537:/usr/lib/firmware/brcm$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[    3.639401] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.639420] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.639423] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.639426] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.639429] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.809329] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[    3.810479] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[    3.826379] Bluetooth: hci0: DESKTOP-DUOEBVI
[    3.830335] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0341
[    4.641338] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0341
[    4.657337] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 Generic USB Class 2 NonUHE @ 20 MHz
[    5.769890] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.769892] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.769896] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   19.887946] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   19.887950] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   19.887955] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

The device is found:

```
silviu@silviu-Inspiron-3537:/usr/lib/firmware/brcm$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller F8:2F:A8:DE:8E:4E Discovering: yes
[CHG] Device 2C:BA:BA:55:9B:1A RSSI: -59
[CHG] Device 2C:BA:BA:55:9B:1A Modalias is nil
[CHG] Device 2C:BA:BA:55:9B:1A RSSI: -73
[CHG] Device 2C:BA:BA:55:9B:1A RSSI: -51
[bluetooth]# devices
Device 2C:BA:BA:55:9B:1A Samsung U Flex (9B1A)
```

And already paired:

```
[bluetooth]# pair 2C:BA:BA:55:9B:1A
Attempting to pair with 2C:BA:BA:55:9B:1A
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists
```

When connecting with blueman using the device name in the recent connections menu it throws this notification:

> **Failed to connect.**
>
> Resource temporarily unavailable.

And related to the bluetooth service, the output of `sudo service bluetooth status` is:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-03-24 15:49:57 EET; 1h 57min left
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 804 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 2.4M
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─804 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

mar 24 15:49:57 silviu-Inspiron-3537 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
mar 24 15:49:57 silviu-Inspiron-3537 bluetoothd[804]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
mar 24 15:49:57 silviu-Inspiron-3537 bluetoothd[804]: Starting SDP server
mar 24 15:49:57 silviu-Inspiron-3537 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
mar 24 15:49:57 silviu-Inspiron-3537 bluetoothd[804]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
mar 24 15:50:11 silviu-Inspiron-3537 bluetoothd[804]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.205 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
mar 24 15:50:11 silviu-Inspiron-3537 bluetoothd[804]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.205 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
```

Also, how can I make the device U Flex work with Skype? Before the first reboots that made the device unusable on Ubuntu again, I could have heard the other person, but from my side there was only noise. On Facebook there was noise on both directions.

Thank you.

Comment: get the missing firmware from https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/tree/master/brcm

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thank you! You can post an answer if you wish. How can I make the device U Flex work with Skype? I can hear the other person, but from my side there is only noise. On Facebook there is noise on both directions.

Comment: It might actually be considered a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working  Most people can get the firmware from the winterheart github now rather than mess with Windows drivers

Comment: @Jeremy31 I added a big update to the question. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.