# Bluetooth can't discover devices Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, dell

My laptop can't discover Bluetooth devices it is just stuck on searching for devices. 
Below is my output for things i tried after reading for similar problems

```
dmesg | grep -i bluetooth # Shows all Bluetooth driver info[   24.488723] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   24.488756] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   24.488760] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   24.488764] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   24.488769] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   25.090501] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   25.091484] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[   25.107492] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[   25.111494] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[   25.285626] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd failed with error -2
[   25.285631] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd not found
[   27.296317] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   27.297513] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[   33.923861] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   33.923864] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   33.923871] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   62.988864] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   62.988877] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   62.988889] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[22813.924999] Modules linked in: btrfs xor zstd_compress raid6_pq ufs qnx4 hfsplus hfs minix ntfs msdos jfs xfs cpuid rfcomm cmac bnep btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic ecc rtsx_usb_ms memstick intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common uvcvideo x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel wl(POE) kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper dell_laptop dell_smm_hwmon mei_hdcp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic intel_cstate nouveau intel_rapl_perf ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi dell_wmi dell_smbios input_leds dcdbas ttm i915 serio_raw dell_wmi_descriptor snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt wmi_bmof sparse_keymap snd_hda_codec joydev mxm_wmi snd_hda_core drm_kms_helper snd_hwdep snd_pcm cfg80211 snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq drm mei_me i2c_algo_bit snd_seq_device snd_timer dw_dmac dw_dmac_core mei fb_sys_fops snd syscopyarea soundcore sysfillrect sysimgblt lpc_ich mac_hid
[22841.797299] Modules linked in: btrfs xor zstd_compress raid6_pq ufs qnx4 hfsplus hfs minix ntfs msdos jfs xfs cpuid rfcomm cmac bnep btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic ecc rtsx_usb_ms memstick intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common uvcvideo x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel wl(POE) kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper dell_laptop dell_smm_hwmon mei_hdcp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic intel_cstate nouveau intel_rapl_perf ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi dell_wmi dell_smbios input_leds dcdbas ttm i915 serio_raw dell_wmi_descriptor snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt wmi_bmof sparse_keymap snd_hda_codec joydev mxm_wmi snd_hda_core drm_kms_helper snd_hwdep snd_pcm cfg80211 snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq drm mei_me i2c_algo_bit snd_seq_device snd_timer dw_dmac dw_dmac_core mei fb_sys_fops snd syscopyarea soundcore sysfillrect sysimgblt lpc_ich mac_hid
[23305.511744] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[23305.512740] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[23305.528773] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[23305.529757] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[23307.339857] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd failed with error -2
[23307.339865] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd not found
[23309.344962] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[23309.345832] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[23341.720819] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[23341.721784] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[23341.737813] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[23341.738864] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[23341.738903] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd failed with error -2
[23341.738907] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd not found
[23372.329439] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[23372.330316] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[23372.346460] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[23372.347309] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[23372.347389] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd failed with error -2
[23372.347399] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd not found
[23374.375018] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[23374.376219] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[23403.087003] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[23403.087996] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[23403.104000] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[23403.104997] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[23403.105033] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd failed with error -2
[23403.105037] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd not found
[23405.128514] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[23405.130006] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[25694.906120] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[25694.907897] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
batxpool@batxpool:~$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth | grep -i firmware # Shows Bluetooth firmware issues
[   25.285626] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd failed with error -2
[23307.339857] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd failed with error -2
[23341.738903] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd failed with error -2
[23372.347389] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd failed with error -2
[23403.105033] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd failed with error -2
batxpool@batxpool:~$
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working)