# Bluetooth not discovering any device on 20.04

Tags: bluetooth, 20.04

I installed 20.04 and the bluetooth is not working . Its not detecting any other device. HELP !

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2b8b Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: I couldn't understand what u said.

Comment: Open a terminal, paste there the command, then [edit] your question and past the result there. Is it more clear now?

Comment: So where is the output? You need to press Enter to get the output. It seems you need to learn using the system first a bit, before this problem can be fixed.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the result there. It is unreadable in comments.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working But that may be too complex for your skills.

Comment: should i do it? as per the link

Comment: Yes, this is the solution. You need firmware.

Comment: stuck on the second step..Downloaded driver file is not opening by archives manager.

Comment: Which one did you download and what happens?

Comment: I downloaded the first one and it opens by double click. Extract the folred somewhere, then you'll be able to look into it.