# Broadcom BCM4352 Bluetooth lists MAC addresses and doesn't connect properly (WiFi fine)

Tags: 18.04, drivers, bluetooth, broadcom

[image: Screenshot of Bluetooth Device Wizard]
[image: Screenshot of available Bluetooth Devices in the systray]

As you can see, the Bluetooth connection wizard does not work properly in (K)Ubuntu 18.04. I'm using an ASUS motherboard (Maximus VII Formula) with a WiFi PCI expansion using a Broadcom chip.

The specific output of `lspci -nnk` is as follows:

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1043:855c]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

**Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter   (rev 03)**

The WiFi adapter works fine. But it would seem that the Bluetooth adapter has broken functionality.

The only noticeable error is that it lists MAC addresses rather than the names of the devices. I will update soon with the same OS on my laptop to show the difference. It simply does not connect, and with MAC addresses, I am also unable to see which device it is - but I've gone through them all in connection attempts.

Output of command requested `dmesg | grep -i blue` by user Pilot:

```
 defaye@defaye  ~  dmesg | grep -i blue
[    3.593365] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.593376] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.593378] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.593379] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.593381] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.719564] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
[    3.720561] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x07
[    3.736566] Bluetooth: hci0: defaye
[    3.737560] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[    3.738438] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0b05-17cf.hcd failed with error -2
[    3.738440] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0b05-17cf.hcd not found
[    6.361037] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.361039] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.361043] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   16.847724] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   16.847730] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   16.847734] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[251934.668433] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
[251934.669431] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x07
[251934.685476] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A
[251934.686460] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[251934.686500] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0b05-17cf.hcd failed with error -2
[251934.686503] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0b05-17cf.hcd not found
```

Comment: Can you elaborate "As you can see, the Bluetooth connection wizard does not work properly"? I don't see anything not working properly. What is the real problem?

Comment: The only noticeable error is that it lists MAC addresses rather than the names of the devices. I will update soon with the same OS on my laptop to show the difference. It simply does not connect, and with MAC addresses, I am also unable to see which device it is - but I've gone through them all in connection attempts.

Comment: @SasukeUchiha What "drivers" are you asning about. There is no BT drivers that can be "updated".

Comment: So mention that it doesn't connect in your question. It is not obvious. Did you click a device and press "Next"?

Comment: Will do, it was implied, but understand

Comment: So did you click "Next"? And what happened?

Comment: @Pilot6 is right. You haven't given enough info on what you already tried. Also I think this will be better if we do this is a chat rather than in comments.

Comment: Give me some time to update what I've tried.  And yes, I've exhaustively gone through the wizard trying to connect.

Comment: I suspect you need firmware for this BT.

Comment: So you need `BCM20702A1-0b05-17cf.hcd`. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working/

Comment: Looking into this solution now @Pilot6

Comment: I'll give you an instruction.

Comment: I think these may help too. https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/blob/master/brcm/BCM20702A1-0b05-17cf.hcd https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Second solution (noticed not written by you but all credit goes to you Pilot6 for helping me come to it) I think hopefully works - which does link to winterheart github page.

Comment: Success! I still see some MAC addresses but I also see my JBL Clip 3 listed properly now and it connects successfully! Thank you guys.
`[    3.983607] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 1469
[    3.999610] Bluetooth: hci0: Broadcom Bluetooth Device
`

Comment: I could also convert lots of firmwares, but uploding them to github is an illegal activity ;-)

Comment: I wrote an answer mentioning both ways of getting the file.

Comment: If you'd like to offer a solution, I will accept the solution mate, thank you so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need firmware for this Bluetooth device. Here is how to get it and convert for Linux:

1. Download this Windows driver. http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/BLUETOOTH/Broadcom/ASUS-X99-DELUXE-Broadcom-Bluetooth-Driver-6515800-12009860.shtml#download
2. Extract `Bluetooth_Win7-8-8-1_V6515800_12009860` from the archive.
3. Under Win8_Win81 -> Win64 directory you'll find `BCM20702A1_001.002.014.1443.1469.hex` file.
4. Convert it to `BCM20702A1-0b05-17cf.hcd` as mentioned here using `hex2hcd`:

[Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working/)

5. Copy it to `/lib/firmware/brcm`

You can try to find an already converted file in some githubs.

For example [this one](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware) has it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the BCM20702A1-0b05-17cf.hcd file from [Winterhart's Github page](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/blob/master/brcm/BCM20702A1-0b05-17cf.hcd)
2. Copy it to `/lib/firmware/brcm`