# No bluetooth devices recognized | problems with drivers (?)

Tags: drivers, 20.04, bluetooth

I'm quite new to Ubuntu 20.04 (and Linux) and spent some time fixing my problem with bluetooth not being able to find any devices.

[Lubuntu 20.04 bluetooth devices not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242463/lubuntu-20-04-bluetooth-devices-not-detected)
Not sure, but I think this is the closest to my problem.

```
dmesg | grep -i 'blue'
[    4.542033] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.542054] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.542060] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.542074] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.542077] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.711132] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[    4.712132] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[    4.728141] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[    4.728145] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[    4.730896] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried:
[    4.730901] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd'
[    4.730902] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM-105b-e065.hcd'
[    6.753354] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[    6.754147] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[    7.707035] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    7.707037] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    7.707042] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   21.550716] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   21.550722] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   21.550729] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working/632348#632348

Comment: Did you put the hcd file to `/lib/firmware/brcm`?

Comment: @Pilot6 the manufactor only provides exe files.
https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/ch/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/g50-80/downloads/driver-list/component?name=Bluetooth%20and%20Modem

Comment: @Pilot6 I'm downloading from here https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware as suggested on the site you sent me.

Comment: So, it should fix the problem.

Comment: @Pilot6 Now it worked after turning off and on again, halleljuah! Thank you and God bless you and your family.