# No bluetooth found Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, usb, bluetooth

I have attached a USB Bluetooth dongle to my PC (with ubuntu 18.04) but I always get No bluetooth found.  I have tried the dongle in Ubuntu 16 and it works. Also literally I have tried all solutions that I found but no success...

Here are some outputs:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net

05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0e)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:8619]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
05:00.1 Serial controller [0700]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:816a] (rev 0e)

lsusb

Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 03f0:604a Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 0a5c:bd1e Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

rfkill list

2: phy2: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

uname -r

5.3.0-62-generic

dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm

No output
```

I would be so grateful if you let me know your suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working)

Comment: Nothing happened :( @Pilot6

Comment: Actually I did not get what .hcd I should copy to /lib/firmware/brcm/