# Bluetooth on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: bluetooth

I downloaded Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on my laptop yesterday as dual boot but whenever I try to connect any device with bluetooth the bluetooth keeps saying "searching for devices and when I try to connect to my Ubuntu machine from a phone it still does not show up in available devices:

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2b8b Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1ea7:0064 SHARKOON Technologies GmbH 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: ok done (.......)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working)