# Bluetooth not working on Ubuntu - Sony Vaio Laptop

Tags: bluetooth, laptop, sony

This is my first question here on askubuntu.com.

I am an absolute beginner and installed ubuntu dual boot with windows 10.
At first, the bluetooth on ubuntu didn't work for some reason, and I did a google search and just did that (mostly askubuntu or quora) and it worked!

Then, bluetooth on my windows 10 stopped working. I tried to install a driver for that but it still didn't work. When I came back to ubuntu, even bluetooth here doesn't work.

**Bluetooth Module: BCM43142A0 Broadcom bluetooth adapter**

EDIT:
demsg shows a bluetooth error

```
hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0489-e062.hcd not found
[  990.110777] audit: type=1400 audit(1607238711.750:120): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.bluetoothctl" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=7452 comm="bluetoothctl" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[ 1230.006319] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
```

I saw somewhere that we will have to manually download and put the .hcd file. I did so, but didn't help.

Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working)

Comment: No it doesn't. Thanks by the way. I forgot to mention that I tried everything on google.

Comment: If you still have `brcm/BCM43142A0-0489-e062.hcd not found`, then you didn't follow the answer properly. You should have this file.

Comment: oh. I too thought the same at first and retried it. But still the same

Comment: What do you mean by "still the same". Are you having the same error? Is the file there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undo whatever you did on Ubuntu.

Ubuntu is basically missing the bluetooth driver for `Broadcom` and that's all I think.

1. Download [broadcom-bt-firmware](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/releases/download/v12.0.1.1105_p3/broadcom-bt-firmware-10.1.0.1115.deb)
2. install it by using:

```
sudo apt install ./<package-name>.deb
```

**OR**

```
sudo apt install gdebi
sudo gdebi <package-name>.deb
```

I would recommend using `gdebi` as it will automatically install all the dependencies too. Although there are no dependencies for the above package but still it is a good practice to use `gdebi`.

3. Restart.

Comment: There are no dependencies ;-) So there is no need to use gdebi.

Comment: I know but it is a good practice to use gdebi.

Comment: Thank you everyone for this, I'll try this and let you know :)

Comment: It is not a "good practice" to use gdebi. Now apt can install dependencies locally. There is no need in gdebi at all.

Comment: Use whatever you want to but, I prefer gdebi.

Comment: Really, I wanna thank you guys a lot!

Comment: You helped me setup my bluetooth so easily! Thanks a lot. I would be happy to help you in any other way! Please let me know! :)

Comment: @AbhinavPrabhakar help me with this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/623056/403435. I will be really thankful to you!

Comment: Oh sorry, couldn't help you with that