# Bluetooth sometimes not working in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, dell, xps

I have a Dell XPS 17 (9700) and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and sometimes when I boot up, Bluetooth is off and can't be turned on via the Settings UI (toggle does nothing).

The only thing that helps is a power off and start again (reboot does not help).
I have the latest BIOS.

I came across this thread:
[I can't turn on Bluetooth in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403817/i-cant-turn-on-bluetooth-in-ubuntu-22-04-lts)

But my problem seems to be slightly different. Here are the outputs of the commands that were suggested in the other thread.
The last command says "bluetooth service is up", but the UI says it is off and none of my devices work.

```
sudo dmesg |grep -i bluetooth
[    3.303752] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.303785] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    3.303786] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.303791] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.303794] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.303800] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.566854] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    3.566858] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    3.566859] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    3.566879] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    3.566880] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    3.566888] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    3.566942] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    3.567001] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[    3.567057] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    3.567059] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[    3.567074] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[    3.572073] Bluetooth: hci0: setting up ROME/QCA6390
[    3.576164] Bluetooth: hci0: Frame reassembly failed (-84)
[    3.895135] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Product ID   :0x00000010
[    3.895142] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA SOC Version  :0x400a0200
[    3.895143] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA ROM Version  :0x00000200
[    3.895144] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Patch Version:0x00000d2b
[    3.895147] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA controller version 0x02000200
[    3.895150] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Downloading qca/htbtfw20.tlv
[    4.213862] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.213866] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.213871] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    4.850499] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Downloading qca/htnv20.bin
[    5.067693] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA setup on UART is completed
[    5.081405] Bluetooth: hci0: Frame reassembly failed (-84)
[    5.081409] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x8383
[    7.098498] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c58 failed: -110


lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm QCA6390 Wireless Network Adapter [AX500-DBS (2x2)] [17cb:1101] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Rivet Networks QCA6390 Wireless Network Adapter [AX500-DBS (2x2)] [1a56:a501]
    Kernel driver in use: ath11k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath11k_pci
05:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] [8086:15ea] (rev 06)
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 2109:0211 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub             
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6727 Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 413c:b080 Dell Computer Corp. Dell DA20 Adapter
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2109:2211 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 27c6:533c Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted

sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-03-29 08:30:13 CEST; 8min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 904 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 76772)
     Memory: 1.8M
        CPU: 96ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─904 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Mär 29 08:30:13 neptun systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Mär 29 08:30:13 neptun bluetoothd[904]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
Mär 29 08:30:13 neptun systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Mär 29 08:30:13 neptun bluetoothd[904]: Starting SDP server
Mär 29 08:30:13 neptun bluetoothd[904]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
```

In the case of successful boot with Bluetooth, the only the first command output looks different:

```
sudo dmesg |grep -i bluetooth
[    3.326913] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.326927] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    3.326928] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.326931] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.326932] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.326935] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.523625] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    3.523628] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    3.523630] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    3.523918] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    3.523921] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    3.524244] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    3.524738] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    3.525672] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[    3.526480] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    3.526482] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[    3.526518] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[    3.527749] Bluetooth: hci0: setting up ROME/QCA6390
[    3.531821] Bluetooth: Received HCI_IBS_WAKE_ACK in tx state 0
[    3.868227] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Product ID   :0x00000010
[    3.868229] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA SOC Version  :0x400a0200
[    3.868230] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA ROM Version  :0x00000200
[    3.868231] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Patch Version:0x00000d2b
[    3.868232] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA controller version 0x02000200
[    3.868233] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Downloading qca/htbtfw20.tlv
[    4.340432] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.340435] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.340440] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    4.819550] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA Downloading qca/htnv20.bin
[    5.038133] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA setup on UART is completed
[    5.154686] Bluetooth: hci0: Bad flag given (0x1) vs supported (0x0)
[    5.155086] Bluetooth: hci0: Bad flag given (0x1) vs supported (0x0)
[    6.528667] hid-generic 0005:0687:C095.0004: input,hidraw2: BLUETOOTH HID v0.71 Keyboard [CHERRY DW 9000KB] on f4:02:28:5e:ba:5f
[   22.598220] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   22.598226] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   22.598230] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   25.139900] hid-generic 0005:0687:C096.0005: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v0.59 Mouse [CHERRY DW 9000MW] on f4:02:28:5e:ba:5f
[   37.608755] hid-generic 0005:0687:C095.0006: input,hidraw2: BLUETOOTH HID v0.71 Keyboard [CHERRY DW 9000KB] on f4:02:28:5e:ba:5f
[   57.241594] hid-generic 0005:0687:C096.0007: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v0.59 Mouse [CHERRY DW 9000MW] on f4:02:28:5e:ba:5f
[ 4287.566084] Bluetooth: hci0: Ignoring error of Inquiry Cancel command
```

Comment: Have you asked Dell if there might be a known issue.

Comment: I tried to use the website. I am out of warranty and there is only paid phone contact possibility. Not sure if that will be worth the money.

Comment: You could look for a free Dell support forum instead of the paid support.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint @David. I posted it here: https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/Bluetooth-sometimes-not-working-in-Ubuntu-22-04-LTS/m-p/8377156/thread-id/108187