# Bluetooth cannot be enabled in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth

I just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my new desktop and the entire Bluetooth system doesn't work means the toggle doesn't work.

I followed all the steps given in this below link but no luck.

[I can't turn on Bluetooth in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403817/i-cant-turn-on-bluetooth-in-ubuntu-22-04-lts)

```
# lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7927]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e0fd]
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller I225-V [8086:15f3] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Ethernet Controller I225-V [1458:e000]
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a2c:0e24 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd USB Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0489:e10f Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 048d:5702 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. ITE Device
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    7.019909] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    7.019916] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    7.019916] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    7.019918] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    7.019919] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    7.019921] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    7.024087] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -16
[    7.524679] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    7.524681] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    7.524683] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized

# sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-02-09 10:56:40 IST; 3h 34min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 950 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38126)
     Memory: 1.8M
        CPU: 33ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─950 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Feb 09 10:56:40 SOUMEN-PC systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Feb 09 10:56:40 SOUMEN-PC bluetoothd[950]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
Feb 09 10:56:40 SOUMEN-PC systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Feb 09 10:56:40 SOUMEN-PC bluetoothd[950]: Starting SDP server
Feb 09 10:56:40 SOUMEN-PC bluetoothd[950]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
```

Comment: Adding another information: I have Gigabyte Z790 A Elite X WIFI 7 Mother Board with CPU Intel I9 14900K

Comment: Sadly that Mediatek 14c3:7927 WiFi-Bluetooth combined chip does not have a Linux driver yet: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Atorvalds%2Flinux+path%3A%2F%5Edrivers%5C%2Fnet%5C%2Fwireless%5C%2Fmediatek%5C%2F%2F+0x7927&type=code

Comment: Thanks @Daniel T for your prompt answer. Is there any possibility to connect my Bluetooth keyboard(Logitech MX KEYS MINI) by using any Bluetooth dongle or somehow..

Comment: A Bluetooth dongle should indeed work