# Bluetooth not working with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, hp

A month ago, I decided to stop using windows, instead looking for more suitable operating systems for my budget laptop. After skating over various operating systems I was happy with Ubuntu. The issue is, I am unable to discover any nearby Bluetooth signals and I suspect something has gone wrong internally,which might be driver related. Any commands I should run in the terminal? I'm sorry I can't provide any more context seeing as I am only getting used to how Linux Distros work, despite me being extremely familiar and good with windows beforehand

I am running on a HP Stream 14 with AMD R3 Graphics, 2GB Ram, 32GB of storage and an AMD A4 chip-set.

P.S I tried using sudo-lshw but nothing related to Bluetooth showed up.. has something gone wrong?

Comment: For starters, try executing `sudo lshw` — it should show you all devices you have *(at least for buses that allow to query for devices disregarding drivers availability)*, along with their drivers. And search for the word `Bluetooth` in the output. Please copy the part of the output about your Bluetooth device into your answer. *(FTR, there's also `gtk-lshw` graphical utility if you don't want to fiddle with terminal, but please make sure to run it with root permissions)*.

Comment: Ok I’ll post all the terminal results shortly

Comment: About your update: does the laptop by any chance have a hardware switch for bluetooth? If not, then Idk, but try also running a `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth` and see if it has any output. If still no luck, some alternative thoughts: 1. Try to boot with latest Fedora *(no need to install, you can boot it straight from the disk)* and see if it works there. The idea here is that this distro has all system components very recent as opposed to Ubuntu, so that would rule out the question of outdated components. And 2. if you still has windows, try to fetch vendor id/product id of the bluetooth device.

Comment: Ok. I'll try your steps. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: This was the output. Hopefully this is helpful https://pastebin.com/Pr3H1Dwf

Comment: Okay, so judging by the output, your bluetooth requries firmware, but it was not found. Please refer to [this question regarding how to get it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working).