# Bluetooth devices not connecting and error messages in 22.04.1

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, blueman

My bluetooth connections are very sporadic and I often get different error messages in blueman while trying to connect to paired devices. One of them is 'Connection Failed: Input/output error' and another is 'Connection failed: le-connection-about-by-local'. Sometimes my bluetooth mouse is connected but doesn't work and then disconnects. Also, occasionally, if my headphones are connected the sound stutters -- I don't know if that is part of this problem but it might be worth mentioning.

I have the same version of Ubuntu installed on an older laptop and there the bluetooth works fine. I'm hoping this is a software and not a hardware issue.

Here is the output of `inxi -Fxz`

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.15.0-57-lowlatency x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.3.0
    Desktop: MATE 1.26.0 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 82K2 v: IdeaPad Gaming 3 15ACH6
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: SDK0J40700 WIN
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: LENOVO v: H3CN30WW(V2.00)
    date: 06/28/2021
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 37.2 Wh (80.2%) condition: 46.4/45.0 Wh (103.1%)
    volts: 12.1 min: 11.5 model: 0x53 0x4D 0x50 0x00 0x32 0x30 0x 0x4C 0x32
    0x30 0x4D 0x33 0x50 0x4500
    status: Discharging
CPU:
  Info: 6-core model: AMD Ryzen 5 5600H with Radeon Graphics bits: 64
    type: MT MCP arch: Zen 3 rev: 0 cache: L1: 384 KiB L2: 3 MiB L3: 16 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1458 high: 1899 min/max: 400/4280 boost: enabled cores:
    1: 1662 2: 1738 3: 1063 4: 1298 5: 1899 6: 1611 7: 1221 8: 1719 9: 977
    10: 1461 11: 1393 12: 1465 bogomips: 79049
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Mobile] vendor: Lenovo
    driver: nvidia v: 525.60.11 bus-ID: 01:00.0
  Device-2: AMD Cezanne vendor: Lenovo driver: amdgpu v: kernel
    bus-ID: 05:00.0
  Device-3: IMC Networks Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 1-3:3
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X:
    loaded: amdgpu,ati,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa
    gpu: amdgpu resolution: 1920x1080~120Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU/PCIe/SSE2
    v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 525.60.11 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio vendor: Lenovo
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 05:00.1
  Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
    vendor: Lenovo driver: N/A bus-ID: 05:00.5
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h HD Audio vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 05:00.6
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-57-lowlatency running: yes
  Sound Server-2: JACK v: 1.9.20 running: no
  Sound Server-3: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: no
  Sound Server-4: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: Lenovo driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 2000 bus-ID: 02:00.0
  IF: enp2s0 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-2: MEDIATEK MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
    vendor: Lenovo driver: mt7921e v: kernel bus-ID: 03:00.0
  IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Broadcom BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0 type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 1-2:2
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 2 state: up address: <filter>
    bt-v: 2.1 lmp-v: 4.0
  Device-2: Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device type: USB driver: btusb
    v: 0.8 bus-ID: 1-4:4
  Report: ID: hci1 rfk-id: 3 state: up address: <filter> bt-v: 3.0
    lmp-v: 5.2
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 260.6 GiB (54.6%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZALQ512HBLU-00BL2
    size: 476.94 GiB temp: 33.9 C
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 321.04 GiB used: 260.21 GiB (81.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-0
    mapped: nvme0n1p6_crypt
  ID-2: /boot size: 1.88 GiB used: 363.4 MiB (18.8%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5
  ID-3: /boot/efi size: 256 MiB used: 37.5 MiB (14.7%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  Alert: No swap data was found.
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 46.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
  GPU: device: nvidia screen: :0.0 temp: 41 C device: amdgpu temp: 43.0 C
Info:
  Processes: 410 Uptime: 1m Memory: 5.65 GiB used: 2.13 GiB (37.8%)
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.3.0 Packages: 3562 Shell: Bash
  v: 5.1.16 inxi: 3.3.13
```

and here is the output of `sudo dmesg |grep -i bluetooth`:

```
[   15.146287] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   15.146318] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[   15.146320] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   15.146325] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   15.146328] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   15.146331] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   15.305589] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
[   15.307588] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x07
[   15.338576] Bluetooth: hci0: owen-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6 #1
[   15.338580] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[   15.338663] Bluetooth: hci1: Device setup in 138095 usecs
[   15.341727] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried:
[   15.341734] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd'
[   15.341737] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM-0a5c-21e8.hcd'
[   15.477669] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   15.477674] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   15.477680] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   20.269474] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   20.269485] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   20.269492] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   34.392228] Bluetooth: hci0: corrupted ACL packet
[   34.504588] Bluetooth: hci0: corrupted ACL packet
[   34.505068] Bluetooth: hci0: corrupted ACL packet
[   34.538469] Bluetooth: hci0: ACL packet for unknown connection handle 2816
[   34.549697] Bluetooth: hci0: corrupted ACL packet
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working)

Comment: I see on this post that the issue is with Broadcom drivers. I've had problems both with my internal bluetooth adapter and my external one. At the moment my problem is with the external one. This is the adapter I am using: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B009ZIILLI/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1. Do they both use Broadcom drivers?

Comment: I think I may have fixed it -- like I said the problem is currently with my external adapter so I unplugged it and plugged it back in again and the problem went away. I'll keep testing and post a solution if it continues to work

Answer (score 0):

Due to a mysterious problem with my external adapter, when I have this problem I have to unplug the adapter and plug it back in; this fixes the problem.