# Bluetooth stopped working after hot swap

Tags: usb, 22.04, bluetooth, lsusb

I (live) removed one USB BT dongle and plugged in a different one. I won't do that again. Now I can turn Bluetooth on, but no BT devices (speakers, keyboard) are ever found.

`lsusb` gives:

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 105b:e065 Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142 Bluetooth module
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
```

`dmesg` reports not finding firmware patches for either:

```
[    9.334699] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried:
[    9.334704] Bluetooth: hci1: BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried:
[    9.334706] Bluetooth: hci1: BCM: 'brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd'
[    9.334707] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd'
```

I've seen other similar posts, but none shows two USB Bluetooth devices.

I put the keyboard and speaker in discovery mode.

Comment: You can find those firmware files at https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/tree/master/brcm and copy them into /lib/firmware/brcm

Comment: Thanks very much that was it. Working fine. Related question if it's easy to answer: Why do those files disappear or were they never there?

Comment: They weren't there as the Broadcom license doesn't allow them to be distributed in Linux, this question is basically a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working

Answer (score 0):

As @Jeremy31 suggested, I got the firmware files from https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/tree/master/brcm and copied them into `/lib/firmware/brcm`.

I'm not sure if it was necessary but once the files recommended by @Jeremy31 were in the right place I did:

```
sudo chmod +wx *.hcd

sudo reboot
```