# Bluetooth option turning off on it's own

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, lenovo

So im relatively new to linux but i have tried a lot of fixes but cant seem to fix the bluetooth problem.

When i go to bluetooth options and toggle it, it turns off immediately
i tried installing bluez and stuff but still didnt work, tried service bluetooth restart, didnt work

i tried running `hciconfig` and i got this:

```
    BD Address: 14:2D:27:E6:37:40  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:328 acl:0 sco:0 events:8 errors:0
    TX bytes:27 acl:0 sco:0 commands:9 errors:0
```

tried `sudo hciconfig -a hci0 up` too but i got this:
`Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)`

can anyone help me out with this?

here are some outputs that may help

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue`:

```
    Subsystem: Lenovo BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [17aa:0621]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: wl
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 105b:e065 Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth module
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 5986:055d Bison Electronics Inc. Lenovo EasyCamera
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
```

`sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service`:

```
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-11-13 13:47:02 +03; 14min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 37881 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4483)
     Memory: 1004.0K
        CPU: 61ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─37881 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Nov 13 13:47:02 amal-jose-Lenovo-G50-70 systemd[1]: Starting bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service...
Nov 13 13:47:02 amal-jose-Lenovo-G50-70 bluetoothd[37881]: Bluetooth daemon 5.68
Nov 13 13:47:02 amal-jose-Lenovo-G50-70 systemd[1]: Started bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service.
Nov 13 13:47:02 amal-jose-Lenovo-G50-70 bluetoothd[37881]: Starting SDP server
Nov 13 13:47:02 amal-jose-Lenovo-G50-70 bluetoothd[37881]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support csip plugin
Nov 13 13:47:02 amal-jose-Lenovo-G50-70 bluetoothd[37881]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support vcp plugin
Nov 13 13:47:02 amal-jose-Lenovo-G50-70 bluetoothd[37881]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support mcp plugin
Nov 13 13:47:02 amal-jose-Lenovo-G50-70 bluetoothd[37881]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support bass plugin
Nov 13 13:47:02 amal-jose-Lenovo-G50-70 bluetoothd[37881]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support bap plugin
Nov 13 13:47:02 amal-jose-Lenovo-G50-70 bluetoothd[37881]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
```

`sudo dmesg |grep -i bluetooth`:

```
[   16.263101] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[   16.263102] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   16.263117] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   16.263118] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   16.263122] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   17.454391] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   17.455339] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[   17.471346] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[   17.471356] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[   17.702978] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried:
[   17.703027] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd'
[   17.703052] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM-105b-e065.hcd'
[   19.720770] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   19.724748] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x1003 failed: -110
[   26.743073] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   26.743081] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   26.743089] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working