BCM43142A0 Broadcom Bluetooth not working on 24.04
Long since I tried to make this work, but failed because of lack of knowledge & understanding in the matter.
Situation
Bluetooth works on Windows, albeit not the best. I don't need the Bluetooth, but I want to use an HP Presenter mouse. This worked on Windows, doesn't on Linux, and I believe the hardware to be at fault.
Years ago I found a post on Arch detailing how someone made it work, but I couldn't understand what it said, very much like the attached post below, but it ended up being much simpler than first thought.
Specifications
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:57c4 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. HP Truevision HD
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 062a:5110 MosArt Semiconductor Corp. ASUS Zen AIO KB/MS/RF/GOLD
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:216d Broadcom Corp. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'
[    0.681328] ACPI: thermal: [Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (-274000)
[    0.692346] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: Bad ACPI memory layout
[    1.218245] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: [Firmware Info]: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 has zero instances
[    1.218253] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: [Firmware Info]: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 has zero instances
[    1.218257] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: [Firmware Info]: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 has zero instances
[    1.218260] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: [Firmware Info]: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 has zero instances
[    1.225581] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:01: [Firmware Info]: 8232DE3D-663D-4327-A8F4-E293ADB9BF05 has zero instances
[    1.225586] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:01: [Firmware Info]: 8F1F6436-9F42-42C8-BADC-0E9424F20C9A has zero instances
[    1.225589] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:01: [Firmware Info]: 8F1F6435-9F42-42C8-BADC-0E9424F20C9A has zero instances
[    1.225592] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:01: [Firmware Info]: DF4E63B6-3BBC-4858-9737-C74F82F821F3 has zero instances
[    3.677869] systemd[1]: Mounting snap-firmware\x2dupdater-127.mount - Mount unit for firmware-updater, revision 127...
[    5.781063] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin (v1.27)
[    5.862033] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.864078] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    5.864083] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.864147] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.864150] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.864158] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.958165] ACPI: video: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PXSX) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    6.037631] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[    6.038647] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[    6.057361] Bluetooth: hci0: denis-HP-Pavilion-Notebook
[    6.057367] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[    6.060776] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried:
[    6.060784] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216d.hcd'
[    6.060788] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM-0a5c-216d.hcd'
[    7.497292] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    7.497297] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    7.497303] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    8.123695] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x1003 failed: -110
[ 1206.241636] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[ 1206.242664] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[ 1206.258679] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[ 1206.258686] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[ 1206.259741] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried:
[ 1206.259746] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216d.hcd'
[ 1206.259748] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM-0a5c-216d.hcd'
[ 1208.263754] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[ 1208.263756] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x1003 failed: -110

Similar Posts
I believe this post addresses it, but I tried it and it doesn't work for me.
BCM43142A0 Broadcom Bluetooth doesn't work with Ubuntu 18.04
Attempted

Found the Windows .hex file & moved over to Linux,
Ran file through hex2hcd
Copied the result over to /lib/firmware/brcm, titled BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0311.0329.hcd
Rebooted, Failed, so copied & renamed file to lowercase (bcm43142a...) and only beginning, as I think the OP of referenced post did (BCM.hcd).
Rebooted, Failed.

Additional
If I attempt anything else, I will update this post.

Please edit to include results from terminal for lsusb; sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'

cd /lib/firmware/brcm  && sudo wget https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/raw/master/brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216d.hcd then reboot.  This is all in https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working

Thank you @Jeremy31, that worked!
Considering how many years it took me to get this working, I wish someone would add this in the default drivers.
HP Presenter works perfectly now.

There are license issues with the Broadcom Bluetooth firmware and it can't be distributed legally at this time
